# Наследование и использование статического вектора в C++

Tags: stl, vector, c++

Есть базовый класc, в котором мне нужно иметь статический вектор, куда я буду заносить некоторые значения в конструкторах наследников:

```
class Base  
{  
    protected:  
        //В этом классе статический вектор  
        static std::vector<double> Vect;  

        //...  
};
```

В конструкторе наследника я делаю так:

```
Class Deriv : public Base  
{  
    Deriv()  
    {
        //.. кроме инициализации членов рассчитываю n и хочу занести в вектор 
        Vect.push_back(n);  
    }    
};
```

И вот на этом моменте Visual Studio (2010) ругается:

> неразрешенный внешний символ ""protected: static class std::list > Container::VectVol" (?VectVol@Container@@1V?$list@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@A)"

Как правильно организовать вектор в базовом классе, чтобы все наследники могли в него заносить значения?

Comment: Разберитесь, чем ошибки компиляции отличаются от ошибок линковки. Конкретно эта ошибка получается от того, что вы объявили статическую переменную в вашем хэдере, но пропустили ее объявление в единице трансляции (`.cpp` файле). См. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019856/c-initialize-static-variables-in-class

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо не только объявление, но и определение вектора.

Вне объявления класса:

```
class Base  
{  
protected:  
    //В этом классе статический вектор  
    static std::vector<double> Vect;

    //...  
};
```

необходимо добавить в какой-нибудь `.cpp`-файл:

```
std::vector<double> Base::Vect;
```