# Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)

Tags: c++, компоновщик, c++-faq, lnk2019

При попытке сборки программы появляется сообщение об ошибке одного из следующих видов:

> - ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ ...
> - неопределённая ссылка на символ ...
> - unresolved external symbol ...
> - undefined reference to ...
> - ошибка LNK2019 ...
> - LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ...

Что это значит, и как исправить такую ошибку?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/3240681

Answer (score 103, accepted):

### Определение

Данная ошибка означает, что в процессе компоновки программы, компоновщик не смог найти определение некоторой сущности, на которую есть ссылка (попытка использования) в программе.

К таким сущностям может относиться, например, функция или переменная.

---

### Причины и решения

Возможных причин появления ошибки может быть несколько и это зависит от того, что представляет из себя собираемый проект. Всё множество ситуаций можно разбить на две большие группы:

---

#### 1. Используются сторонние или собственные библиотеки

##### Не указана необходимая (статическая) библиотека для компоновщика.

Например, к проекту подключен только `*.h` файл с объявлениями, но отсутствует код реализации, обычно это `*.lib` или `*.a` файлы (в зависимости от используемой системы).
Требуется явно подключить библиотеку к проекту.

- Для *Visual C++* это можно сделать добавлением следующей строки прямо в код:

  ```
  #pragma comment(lib, "libname.lib")
  ```
- Для *gcc/clang* требуется указать файл через ключ `-l` (эль)
- Для Qt в *.pro* файле нужно использовать переменную `LIBS`:

  ```
  LIBS += -L[путь_к_библиотеке] -l[имя_библиотеки]
  ```
- Для системы сборки *CMake* есть [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

##### Библиотека указана, но необходимая сущность, например, класс или функция фактически не экспортируется из библиотеки.

Под Windows это может возникать из-за отсуствия [`__declspec(dllexport)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport) перед сущностью. Обычно это [решается макросами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/995811/176217). Важно, чтобы признак экспортируемости был доступен в той же единице трансляции, где определена экспортируемая сущность. Например, если `__declspec(dllexport)` указано для функции в заголовочном файле, но этот файл не включили (через `#include`) в модуль, где определена функция, то эта функция не будет экспортирована. Данная ситуация чаще всего характерна именно для библиотек, находящихся в процессе разработки, и доступных для модификации самому разработчику, нежели для каких-то стабильных версий действительно внешних для проекта библиотек. После разрешения экспортирования библиотеку, конечно же, нужно пересобрать перед непосредственным использованием проблемной сущности.

##### Библиотека указана, но не совпадает разрядность библиотеки и компилируемого кода.

В общем случае, разрядность собираемого проекта (приложения или библиотеки) должна совпадать с разрядностью используемой сторонней библиотеки. Обычно производители библиотек предоставляют возможность выбора 32 или 64 бит версию использовать. Если библиотека поставляется в исходных кодах и собирается отдельно от текущего проекта, нужно также выбрать правильную разрядность.

##### Библиотека указана, но она собрана для другой (не совместимой) ОС.

Например при сборке проекта в Windows осуществляется попытка использовать бинарный файл, собранный для Linux. В данном случае нужно использовать файлы, подходящие для вашей ОС.

##### Библиотека указана, но она собрана другим компилятором, не совместимым с используемым.

Объектные файлы, полученные путем сборки C++ кода разными компиляторами для одной и той же ОС могут быть бинарно несовместимы друг с другом. Требуется использовать совместимые (скорее всего и вовсе одинаковые) компиляторы.

##### Библиотека указана, и собрана тем же компилятором, что и основной проект, но используются разные версии Run-Time библиотек.

Например, для Visual C++ возможна ситуация, когда библиотека собрана с ключом `/MDd`, а основной проект с `/MTd`. Требуется задать ключи так, чтобы использовались одинаковые версии Run-Time библиотек.

##### Библиотека указана, но нарушен порядок, в котором указаны зависимости.

Например, для [GCC компоновщика](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) зависимая сущность должна быть указана раньше (левее):

```
foo.o -lz bar.o // просматривает библиотеку 'z' после foo.o, но перед bar.o
```

Если `bar.o` ссылается на функции в `z`, то эти функции могут быть не загружены.

---

#### 2. Сторонние или собственные библиотеки не используются

##### Просто отсутствует определение функции.

```
void f(int); // всего лишь объявление. Нет `тела` функции

int main(){  
    f(42);   // undefined reference to `f(int)'
}
```

Требуется добавить определение функции `f`:

```
void f(int) {
    // тело функции
}
```

Может быть ещё частный случай с ошибкой вида:

> ```
> undefined reference to `vtable for <имя_класса>`
> ```

Такая ошибка возникает, если объявленная виртуальная функция класса, не являющаяся чистой (`=0`), не содержит реализации.

```
class C {
    virtual void f(int);
};
```

Нужно такую реализацию добавить. Если это делается вне класса, надо не забыть указать имя проблемного класса, иначе это будет просто свободная функция, которая не устраняет указанную проблему:

```
void C::f(int) { // виртуальная функция-член вне определения класса
    // тело функции  
}
```

```
void f(int) { // свободная функция, не устраняющая проблему
    // тело функции 
}
```

Аналогичная ситуация может возникать при использовании пространств имён, когда объявлении функции находится в пространстве имён:

```
// В заголовочном файле
namespace N {
    void f(int);
};
```

а при реализации указать это пространство имён забыли:

```
// В файле реализации
void f(int) { // функция в глобальном пространстве имён, не устраняющая проблему
    // тело функции  
}
```

```
namespace N {
    void f(int) { // функция в нужном пространстве имён
        // тело функции  
    }
} // конец пространства имён
```

Стоит заметить, что C++ разрешает перегрузку функций (существование одноимённых функций, но с разным набором параметров), и в этом случае важно, чтобы сигнатуры функций при объявлении и определении совпадали. Например, вместо объявленной `void f(int)` была реализована другая:

```
void f(const char*) { // const char* вместо int
    // тело функции     
}
```

При вызове `f(42)` будет ошибка:

> ```
> undefined reference to `f(int)'
> ```

Наличие связки шаблонного класса и дружественной функции также может приводить к ошибке. Например:

```
template <class T>
struct C {
    friend void f(C<T>); // объявляет *НЕ*шаблонную дружественную функцию
};

template <class T>       // определяет шаблонную функцию 
void f(C<T>) { }

int main() {
    C<int> c;
    f(c);                // undefined reference to `f(C<int>)'
}
```

Чтобы объявить шаблонную дружественную функцию, требуется добавить указание шаблонности:

```
template <class T>
struct C {
    template <class V>     // добавили шаблонность для friend функции
    friend void f(C<T>);
};
```

Важно, что имя шаблонного параметра для дружественной функции должно отличаться от имени параметра шаблонного класса `T`, т.к. иначе будет ошибка о сокрытии имени. В частном случае имя класса можно вовсе не указывать, и оставить `template <class>`. Но это не всегда будет правильным решением, т.к. фактически могла потребоваться дружественная *специализация* шаблона функции, а не сама шаблонная функция. Подробнее об использовании дружественных функций в шаблонном классе можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495141/176217).

##### Отсутствует определение статической переменной класса.

```
struct S {
    static int i;
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.i = 42;  // undefined reference to `S::i'
}
```

Нужно добавить определение (выделить память) переменной:

```
int S::i;
```

##### Неправильная реализация шаблонного кода.

Например, реализация шаблонного кода помещена в `*.cpp` файл, хотя она должна находиться полностью в подключаемом `*.h` файле. Это требуется по той причине, что компилятор обрабатывает каждый модуль независимо, и в момент инстанцирования шаблона (подстановки конкретного типа) код его реализации должен быть виден. При этом если возможные типы шаблона известны заранее, можно произвести инстанцирование сразу рядом с телом шаблона и не предоставлять его наружу в исходном коде заголовочного файла. Пример:

```
// unit.h
#pragma once

template <class T>
T f(T);                    // объявление шаблона без реализации
```

```
// unit.cpp
#include "unit.h"

template <class T>
T f(T t) { return t + t; } // реализация шаблона

template
int f<int>(int);           // явное инстанцирование для int

template
double f<double>(double);  // явное инстанцирование для double
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "unit.h"

int main() { 
    f(2);   // ok int
    f(1.5); // ok double
    f('a'); // undefined reference to `char f<char>(char)'
}
```

##### Файл с кодом не был скомпилирован.

Например, в случае использования make-файла не было прописано правило построения файла, а в случае использования IDE типа Visual Studio `*.cpp` файл не добавлен в список файлов проекта.

##### Виртуальная функция в базовом классе не объявлена как `= 0` (pure-virtual).

```
struct B {
    virtual void f();
};

struct D : B {
    void f() {}
};

int main() {
    D d;
}
```

При использовании иерархии классов функция в базовом классе, не имеющая реализации должна быть помечена как "чистая":

```
struct B {
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
```

##### Имя не имеет внешнего связывания.

Например, есть объявление функции `f` в модуле `А` и даже ее реализация в модуле `B`, но реализация помечена как `static`:

```
// A.cpp
void f();
int main() {
    f();   // undefined reference to `f()'
}

// B.cpp
static void f() {}
```

Аналогичная ситуация может возникнуть при использовании безымянного пространства имен:

```
// B.cpp
namespace {
   void f() {}
}
```

Или даже при наличии `inline` у функции:

```
// B.cpp
inline void f() {}
```

Comment: Разве разные версии рантайма могут быть причиной такой ошибки? По-идее, должны оба рантайма слинковаться...

Comment: @PavelMayorov `Все модули, передаваемые компоновщику при конкретном вызове, должны компилироваться с одним и тем же параметром компилятора, указывающим библиотеку времени выполнения (/MD, /MT, /LD).` [отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx)

Comment: Я в курсе. Но точно ли именно такая ошибка возникает, если это требование нарушить?

Comment: @PavelMayorov например вот [ответ на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14158187/3240681).

Comment: ...в котором буржуйским по белому написано, что при несовпадении ключей получается варнинг, а не ошибка unresolved symbol.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну а теперь на вопрос посмотрите и логи, которые привел автор.

Comment: Это вы посмотрите. Там 1 предупреждение LNK4098 - и 13 ошибок, связанных с WinAPI (не с рантаймом!).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46796/discussion-between-alexolut-and-pavel-mayorov).

Comment: В решении для шаблонного друга, вероятно, имелось в виду `friend void f(C<V>);`. [Пример](https://godbolt.org/z/M8xW49hrP).

Comment: Собирал либу я сам через nmake. На том же компе и пытался импортировать с тем же компилятором. Указал дополнительные каталоги включаемые (для .h файлов), он видит их. Указал каталог для библиотек в компоновщике и название lib файла в доп зависимостях. Перебирал разные флаги /MDd /MTd /MD /MT. Перебирал release, debug, x86, x64. При x86 варнинг что либа 64 битная, но символы как не видел так и не видит. Если заглянуть в dumpbin /symbols то там нужные символы есть и экспортированы. Так же пробовал дописать __declspec(dllexport) в код либы, не помогло. Может кто-нибудь помочь? Либа PQClean.

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas предлагаю опубликовать это отдельным вопросом.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ видимо дело не во мне, а в либе. Они мне предложили попробовать другую, в которой лучше реализована поддержка винды и я сделал все ровно так же как и с предыдущими либами, но теперь все компилируется и работает как надо.

Answer (score 18):

(В дополнение к уже существующему ответу)

- При использовании Visual Studio или других компиляторов для платформы Windows выполнение проекта типа **Windows Desktop Application** начинается с функции `WinMain`, а выполнение проекта типа **Windows Console Application** начинается с функции `main`.

  Если ваша программа написана на обычном С или С++, т.е содержит стандартную классическую функцию `main`, а вы по ошибке создали свой проект с типом **Windows Desktop Application**, то при линковке вы получите сообщение о том, что функция `WinMain` не была найдена линкером.

  И наоборот, если вы создали проект типа **Windows Console Application**, но вместо функции `main` определили в нем функцию `WinMain`, то при линковке вы получите сообщение о том, что функция `main` не была найдена линкером.

Answer (score 4):

Дополнение к ответу αλεχολυτ - как оказалось, некоторые ухитряются объявить чисто виртуальным деструктор:

```
class Base {
    ...
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
```

а такие фокусы недопустимы, так как деструктор базового класса вызывается всегда (кроме случая создания объекта через `new` без соответствующего `delete`). Результат - та же ошибка undefined reference.

Еще одно дополнение — в Visual C++ получение сообщения

> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ WinMain в функции "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ).

Связана с тем, что приложение, написанное, как консольное (с `int main()`) собирается как оконное. Исправьте, войдя в  Проект→Компоновщик→Система→Подсистема и выбрав в списке *Консоль (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)*.

Добавил исключительно для тех, кто будет искать на странице *int __cdecl invoke_main* :)

Comment: если что, чисто виртуальный деструктор — обычный и совершенно нормальный способ сделать класс чисто виртуальным (и запретить его создание)... просто его надо определить...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, и куда его потом девать? Ведь унаследованные от него классы тоже не будут работать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, конечно, будут... почему нет?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, по тому, что в этом ответе написано.

Comment: @Qwertiy, УМВР: https://godbolt.org/z/ed7EbW969

Comment: @Harry, как так?

Comment: @Qwertiy Что здесь не так, как написано у меня? https://ideone.com/qPl7Ud А по ссылке — ну, пусть он его **слинкует** и покажет... Вопрос ведь у нас — напомню — "*ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ*"...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а почему у тебя одновременно и `=0`, и `Base::~Base() {}` в коде? Я только сейчас этот финт заметил.

Comment: @Qwertiy Мда, и я тоже :) Кстати, а что говорит об этом стандарт? О наличии тела у чисто виртуальной функции? Компиляторы-то обычно это позволяют, а стандарт?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я же сразу написал: **просто его надо определить**

Comment: @Harry, [\[class.virtual\]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.virtual#11): *A virtual function declared in a class shall be defined, or declared pure in that class, **or both**; no diagnostic is required*... по поводу ссылки: там и линковка и запуск включены в настройках...

Comment: я, если честно, считал, что это всё «общеизвестная тонкость», поэтому как-то и не заострял на этом внимания...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Меня как-то раз здесь били по рукам, когда я снабдил такую чисто виртуальную функцию телом, так что я решил, что это стандартом не разрешено, но работает :)

Answer (score 2):

Отдельным случаем я бы выделил полное **отсутствие точки входа при компоновке запускаемого модуля**. Другими словами: программист хочет **собрать запускаемую программу, а в исходном коде отсутствует функция [`main()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function):**

> Программа должна иметь глобальную функцию `main`, которая является точкой старта программы в гостевой среде

чаще всего имеющую сигнатуру:

> ```
> int main() { ... }
> ```

или

> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ... }
> ```

Ситуация с отсутствием функции `main()` может возникнуть просто по невнимательности, но чаще всего случается при копировании примеров из интернета, книг и других источников, когда приведенный фрагмент кода является отдельной функцией.

Типичный симптом: сообщения об ошибках, упоминающих неразрешенный внешний символ `main()`.

Пример вопросов:

- [С++ программа при компиляции выдаёт ошибки LNK2019 и LNK1120](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1363893/337980)
- [Ошибка "Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _main в функции ...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1099216/337980)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, это и так все знают, но на всякий случай. Использование inline конструкторов и методов, прописанных в отдельном файле, также может вызывать подобные ошибки. То есть недопустимо писать в .cpp файле такое (для MSVS2022):

```
inline records::records(void) {
    records_amount_ = 0;
    first_record_p_ = nullptr;
}
```

а нужно писать:

```
records::records(void) {
    records_amount_ = 0;
    first_record_p_ = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Это описано в основном ответе. Часть "Имя не имеет внешнего связывания."