# Доступ к static переменной без создания объекта класса

Tags: c++

Добрый день.
После компиляции кода выскакивает ошибка unresolved externals.

```
class Name
{
public:
    static int a;
};

void main()
{
    Name::a = 5;
    cout << Name::a << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Почему? Дейтел вроде говорит, что так можно

Comment: см. [неразрешенный внешний символ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, только нужно правильно написать

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Name
{
public:
    static int a;
};

int Name::a = 5;

int main()
{
    cout << Name::a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в первой строке main при обращении к **объявленному** (declared) но **не определенному** (defined) статическому члену класса действительно имеет место (изначально я ее недосмотрел, минусы в мою сторону в связи с этим вполне оправданы).

Во-вторых, старайтесь не использовать system("pause") для остановки исполнения программы, это системнозависимый непереносимый [нерекомендуемый](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) способ. Для этой цели [лучше](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24776299/5485944) пользоваться стандартным средством std::cin.get() так:

```
#include <iostream>

class Name
{
public:
    static int a;
};

int Name::a = 5;

int main()
{
    Name::a = 5;
    std::cout << Name::a << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
//  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `std::cin.get()` также не нужен. Консольное приложение либо запускается непосредственно в консоли, тогда подобное излишество не нужно, либо с под отладчика, а там есть stub для для этого.

Comment: @KoVadim : Я не пытался судить о задачах, стоящих перед автором вопроса, а исходил из того, что, если человек пишет system("pause"), то, вероятно, этим он преследует конкретную цель.
Кстати, мне периодически встречается подобный код с ожиданием ввода в конце. Никогда не понимал смысла этого, но, возможно, это связано с тем, что в Windows (при настройках по умолчанию) консольное окно закрывается сразу по завершению процесса, его открывшего.

Comment: читайте между строк - "я скопировал код c книги Дейтела, она неведомого года и OCR сделал человек, для которого родной только китайский". Дальше продолжать?