# Как создавать ярлыки средствами С++, WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

Пишу инсталлятор, который, как принято, должен создавать ярлык на рабочем столе и группу в меню Пуск.

Находил в сети много вариантов одной и той же функции создания ярлыков, которая основывается на Shellapi. MinGW при компиляции кода с этой функцией выводит две ошибки:

1. > undefined reference to `CoCreateInstance@20'
2. > undefined reference to `IID_IPersistFile'

При этом в коде ничего не подчёркивая красным. Простой `SHCreateShortcut()` он тоже не понимает. Очень критична статическая компиляция!

Собственно вопрос: неужели кроме как через Шелл никак не создать ярлык? Нельзя ли просто `WriteFile(..."Link.lnk"...)`, предварительно записав в переменную-буфер создаваемого файла нужные пути и наименования после определённой последовательности байт, которая отвечает за идентификацию параметров ярлыка? Если так можно, подскажите пожалуйста эти последовательности (маркеры). Или может есть другие пути создания ярлыков?

Comment: Возможно, у Вас ["Ошибка XY"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710). Почитайте про [возможные причины undefined reference](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Comment: Можно, но зачем? Разберитесь лучше, как подключить shell, а не стройте костыли.

Comment: Да разобрался уже. )) Использую MinGW в NetBeans - в параметрах линковщика нужна строка -lshell32

Answer (score 1):

Видите ли, без `Shell...`, наверное, можно - как-то же MS это делают :)? только это будет сложно и непереносимо - теоретически формат может и поменяться.

У вас же, похоже, проблема просто в том, что к проекту не подключена нужная библиотека (насколько я помню, `Shell32.lib`).

Comment: #pragma comment(lib,"Shell32.lib") и инклудами <Shobjidl.h> и <shlobj.h> не помогают. Как её подключить то?

Comment: Ну, или параметром командной строки, или где-то в среде - тут вам должно быть виднее. Возможно, надо указать каталог для поиска библиотек, или указать к ней полный путь...

Comment: может как-то из консоли при помощи system(), или через batch-файл - при установке создать-выполнить-удалить?