# ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _mysql_init@4 в функции _main

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, visual-studio-2015

Возникла проблема при подключении C++ программы к MYSQL серверу. 
Ошибка:

`ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _mysql_init@4 в функции _main`

Все делал по инструкциям (их было много примерно одинаковых и все время приходил к этой ошибке.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

MYSQL Server 5.7

Comment: Библиотеку для работы с nySQL не забыли подключить?

Comment: Не забыл `#include <mysql.h>`
так тоже пробовал
`#pragma comment(lib, "libmysql.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"mysqlclient.lib")`

Comment: А библиотеки линковщик точно находит? Они в нужных местах лежат?... Просто сообщение говорит о том, что линковщик не может найти использованную в `main` функцию - не объявление из заголовочного файла, а саму библиотеку.

Comment: @Harry  А как проверить, находит ли линковщик библиотеки?
Лежат в нужных местах. Тоесть в тех, куда я указал.

Comment: @Александр линкер ругнется, если указанную lib не найдет. Соответственно вопрос: другие ошибки при сборке есть?

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546)

Comment: @Александр: Библиотекам мало "лежать в нужных местах". Библиотеки должны быть явно скормлены на вход линкеру. Ваш `#pragma comment(lib, "libmysql.lib") ` - это оно, но лучше было бы пока не лезть в новомодные `#pragma comment`, а по старинке указать библиотеки явно прямо во входных настройках линкера.

Answer (score 1):

Очень возможно, что у вас намешано DLL/библиотек от разных версий mysql, соответственно когда подключается динамическая библиотека, может подключиться не та, что нужно, и нужные функции там не находятся.
Попробуйте поискать сколько у вас в системе разных библиотек от mysql.