# Ошибка undefined reference to

Tags: c++, g++

Все в одном .cpp по модулям не делил, надеюсь проблема не в этом. Добавил области видимости к каждой переменной в функциях,в попытке исправить проблему.
Интересна по большей части сама причина почему компилятор не может отработать, как я понял, динамическую компиляции.

Собственно код ошибки компилятора:

```
/tmp/ccJCiuqE.o: In function `Quote::~Quote()':
1501.cpp:(.text._ZN5QuoteD2Ev[_ZN5QuoteD5Ev]+0xd): undefined reference to `vtable for Quote'
/tmp/ccJCiuqE.o:(.rodata._ZTV16Count_disk_quote[_ZTV16Count_disk_quote]+0x28): undefined reference to `Quote::debug()'
/tmp/ccJCiuqE.o:(.rodata._ZTV10Disk_quote[_ZTV10Disk_quote]+0x28): undefined reference to `Quote::debug()'
/tmp/ccJCiuqE.o:(.rodata._ZTI10Disk_quote[_ZTI10Disk_quote]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Quote'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

class Quote

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;


    class Quote{
        public:
        Quote() = default;
        Quote(const string &book, double sales_price):
                bookNo(book), price(sales_price) { }
        string isbn() const {return bookNo;}
        virtual double net_price(size_t) const;
        virtual ~Quote() = default;
        virtual void debug();
        private:
        std::string bookNo;
        protected:
        double price = 0.0;
    };
```

class Disk_quote

```
class Disk_quote : public Quote {
public:
    Disk_quote() = default;
    Disk_quote (const string &book, double price, size_t qty, double disk):
                       Quote(book,price), quantity(qty), discount(disk){ }
    double net_price(size_t) const = 0;
protected:
    size_t quantity = 0;
    double discount=0.0;;
};
```

class Bulk_quote

```
class Bulk_quote: public Disk_quote {
public:
    Bulk_quote() = default;
    Bulk_quote(const string &book, double price, size_t qty, double disk):
                Disk_quote(book,price, qty, disk){ }
    void debug() final;
    double net_price(size_t) const ;
};


double Bulk_quote::net_price(size_t cnt) const {
        if(cnt >= Disk_quote::quantity)
            return cnt * (1-Disk_quote ::discount) * Quote::price;
        else
            return cnt * Quote::price;
}


void Bulk_quote::debug (){
    if(quantity > 0 || Bulk_quote::discount > 0){
        cout<<  Quote::isbn() <<  Quote::price << Disk_quote::quantity << Disk_quote::discount << endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<  Quote::isbn() <<  Quote::price << endl;
}
```

cass Count_disk_quote

```
class Count_disk_quote:public Disk_quote {
public:
    Count_disk_quote() = default;
    Count_disk_quote(const string &book, double price, size_t qty, double disk, size_t max):
                Disk_quote(book,price, qty, disk), max_quantity(max){ }
    double net_price (size_t) const ;
private:
    size_t max_quantity = quantity;
};


double Count_disk_quote::net_price(size_t cnt) const {
    if(cnt <= Count_disk_quote::max_quantity){
        if(cnt >= Disk_quote::quantity)
            return cnt * (1-Disk_quote::discount) * Quote::price;
        else
            return cnt * Quote::price;
    }
    else
        return (Count_disk_quote::max_quantity * (1-Disk_quote::discount) * Quote::price)
                 + ((cnt - Count_disk_quote::max_quantity) * Quote::price);
}

double print_total(ostream &os, const Quote &item, size_t n){
    double ret = item.net_price(n);
    os << "ISBN:" << item.isbn()<< "# sold:" << n << " total due: "<<ret <<endl;
    return ret;
}


int main (){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А где у вас определён `Quote::debug`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как обычно, у вас просто нет определений (тел) двух функций -

```
    virtual double net_price(size_t) const;
    virtual void debug();
```

в класса `Quote`.

Поскольку от него наследует АБСТРАКТНЫЙ класс `Disk_quote`, делаю вывод, что вы просто забыли дописать к объявлениям этих виртуальных функций `=0` и сделать класс `Quote` тоже абстрактным:

```
    virtual double net_price(size_t) const = 0;
    virtual void debug() = 0;
```

Правда, `debug()` у вас все равно остается абстрактным в `Count_disk_quote`, так что, возможно, надо определить `Quote::debug()` и сделать чисто виртуальной `Quote::net_price()`. Смотрите сами, как у вас задумано.

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор не видит определения функции

```
virtual void debug();
```

объявленной в классе `Quote`

Похоже, та же проблема имеет место с другой виртуальной функцией

```
virtual double net_price(size_t) const;
```