# Шаблон не воспринимает char

Tags: c++

**logger.h:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
class Logger
{
public:
    Logger();
    std::stringstream stream;
    std::fstream file;
    operator std::string() const;
    template<typename T>
    Logger& operator<< (const T& arg);
};
```

**logger.cpp:**

```
#include "logger.h"
Logger::Logger()
{

}
template<typename T>
Logger& Logger::operator<< (const T& arg) {
    stream << arg;
    cout << arg;
    if(stream.str().size()>1024)
    {
        savelog();
    }
    return *this;
}
Logger::operator std::string() const {
    return stream.str();
}
```

**logs** - объект класса `Logger`

```
logs << "OK\n";
```

**Выдает ошибку:**

> undefined reference to `Logger& Logger::operator<< (char const (&) [19])'

Что сделать, чтобы код заработал?

Comment: Обратите внимание на [тему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217). Там и о Вашей ситуации есть информация.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку это шаблонная функция, поместите имплементацию внутрь класса.

Дело в том, что при компиляции .cpp компилятор не знает, с какими параметрами ему инстанциировать шаблон. (Он же не может накомпилировать функций на все возможные `T`!)