# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegEnumValueA referenced in function

Tags: c++, компиляция, реестр, jni

Пытаюсь скомпилировать программу на С++, которая хочет прочесть данные о портах в реестре. Знаток С++ я небольшой, я по Java, а это JNI класс, для работы с Java. Уже обгуглися, не понимаю, что он хочет:

> cl -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" myJniClass.cpp /link /DLL Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24210 for x64 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24210.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:myJniClass.dll /dll /implib:myJniClass.lib /DLL myJniClass.obj    Creating library myJniClass.lib and object myJniClass.exp myJniClass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
__imp_RegEnumValueA referenced in function Java_serialport_Serial_getSerialPortNames myJniClass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegOpenKeyExA referenced in function Java_serialport_Serial_getSerialPortNames myJniClass.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Для компиляции скачал `Visual C++ Build Tools` и запустил `Visual C++ 2015 x64 Native Build Tools Command Prompt`. Сам исходник проверенный, без ошибок. Код успешно компилится через Android Studio + NDK.

Вот проблемный фрагмент кода:

```
HKEY phkResult;
LPCSTR lpSubKey = "HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM\\";
jobjectArray returnArray = NULL;
//if(RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &phkResult) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &phkResult) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
    boolean hasMoreElements = true;
    DWORD keysCount = 0;
    char valueName[256];
    DWORD valueNameSize;
    DWORD enumResult;
    while(hasMoreElements){
        valueNameSize = 256;
        //enumResult = RegEnumValueA(phkResult, keysCount, valueName, &valueNameSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        enumResult = RegEnumValue(phkResult, keysCount, valueName, &valueNameSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(enumResult == ERROR_SUCCESS){
            keysCount++;
        } else if(enumResult == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS){
            hasMoreElements = false;
        } else {
            hasMoreElements = false;
        }
    }
```

Конкретно участвует функция `RegEnumValueA`, причём, как видно по ошибке, она превратилась в `__imp_RegOpenKeyExA`. Эта приставка попадается в сгенерированных .lib и .obj. Например:

```
e __imp_PurgeComm __imp_SetCommBreak __imp_SetCommMask __imp_SetCommState __imp_SetCommTimeouts __imp_WaitCommEvent __imp_RegEnumValueA __imp_RegOpenKeyExA
```

Comment: Посмотрите [эту тему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте, не спасет ли вас добавление директивы

```
#pragma comment(lib,"Advapi32")
```

которая говорит о необходимости включение в проект библиотеки Advapi32, в которой, собственно, и находится ваша функция.

Comment: Спасибо. Я попробую и отпишусь.

Comment: А имеет ли значение то, что нужно использовать - Visual Studio, SDK, Visual Studio Build Tools, Visual C++ Build Tools? Я установил только "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 с обновлением 3".

Comment: Visual C++ эту прагму точно понимает. Можно и так, как советует @Mikhajlo - важно, что нужно явно подключить данную библиотеку.

Comment: Вау! Это реально помогло! Я выбрал этот ответ лучшим, так как он проще с точки зрения компиляции, самодостаточнее. Только не пойму, почему без прагмы к нему не придрался компилятор MinGW и Android NDK. и почему он его автоматом не отыскал.

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто добавить в вашей командной строке после .cpp-файла

```
advapi32.lib
```

или то же - после `/link`.

Comment: Спасибо. Я попробую и отпишусь.