# Линкер MVS не находит зависимость OpenGL кода написаного в Qt (ошибка LNK2019)

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio, компоновщик

Есть Qt проект с файлами:

> untitled2.pro

```
 QT += opengl
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    wopengl.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    wopengl.h
```

> main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

> wopengl.h

```
#ifndef WOPENGL_H
#define WOPENGL_H

#include <QGLWidget>

class WOpengl : public QGLWidget{
public:
    void scene();
};

#endif // WOPENGL_H
```

> wopengl.cpp

```
#include "wopengl.h"
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <GL/gl.h>

void WOpengl::scene(){
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

**Параметры сборки проекта:**

```
qmake.exe D:\fil\qt\simple_3D\untitled2.pro -spec win32-msvc2015 "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" && C:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/jom.exe qmake_all
```

**При сборки получаю ошибку:**

> wopengl.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glVertex3f в функции "public: void __cdecl WOpengl::scene(void)" (?scene@WOpengl@@QEAAXXZ)

.....

Из среды идентификатор `glVertex3f` виден, а при сборке нет. Не пойму в чем причина?

.....

**Подробный вывод причины:**

```
15:44:50: Выполняются этапы для проекта untitled2...
15:44:50: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
15:44:50: Запускается: «C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe» 
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\untitled2.exe @C:\Users\vvf\AppData\Local\Temp\untitled2.exe.4844.0.jom
wopengl.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glVertex3f в функции "public: void __cdecl WOpengl::scene(void)" (?scene@WOpengl@@QEAAXXZ)
debug\untitled2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1
jom: D:\fil\qt\build-untitled2-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\untitled2.exe] Error 1120
jom: D:\fil\qt\build-untitled2-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
15:44:50: Процесс «C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта untitled2 (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2015_64bit)
Комплект Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2015_64bit имеет недостатки в конфигурации, которые могут быть источниками данной проблемы.
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
15:44:50: Прошло времени: 00:01.
```

Comment: В среде виден потому что берётся из заголовочников, а при сборке нет, т.к. не линкуется либа, или линкуется не та. Может быть поможет [ответ тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Comment: @alexolut вот эту прагму добовляю `#pragma comment( lib, "OpenGL32.lib" )` и все начинает работать. исходники не мои, почему у него работает (без прагмы) а у меня нет?

Comment: У кого, у него? Ну может компилятор другой, набор библиотек, версия ОС ...

Comment: возможно, человек подложил либу другим способом. Например, он подключил ещё один вложенный проект, который  требует opengl. Сверяйте все!

Comment: Это проект другого автора написанный на QtCreator. Все файлы в одной папке. Я так понимаю когда я в pro-файле пишу `QT += opengl` сборщик должен подключить все нужные для opengl `lib` файлы.

Comment: судя по mkspec похоже так и должно быть. В любом случае, я бы внимательно посмотрел в вывод в окне Compile Output когда  будет отрабатывать линковщик и там искать различия

Comment: @KoVadim добавил подробный вывод в ответ