# Undefined reference to member of class in library

Tags: c++, g++, gnu, library

Итак, у меня есть 1 тестовое приложение и 1 библиотека, которая подключается к приложению. Проблема заключается в том, что, функции неопределенны, но я никак не могу понять почему.
1. Код тестового приложения:
main.cpp

```
#include "log.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Log::Get()->Print("Test %d", 50);

    delete Log::Get();
    return 0;
}
```

и Makefile

```
CC=g++
LINK=g++

LIBARIES=-lDeka

CFLAGS= -c -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall -I ../SDL_DekaLib/include
LINKFLAGS= -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall -I ../SDL_DekaLib/include -L . $(LIBARIES)

all: main.o libDeka.a
    $(LINK) $(LINKFLAGS) main.o -o test.exe

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -o main.o

libDeka.a: log.o
    ar rc libDeka.a log.o

log.o: log.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) log.cpp -o log.o

clean:
    del *.o
    del *.exe
    del *.a
```

ну и для галочки вывод в консоли

```
g++ -c -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall -I ../SDL_DekaLib/include main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -c -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall -I ../SDL_DekaLib/include log.cpp -o log.o
ar rc libDeka.a log.o
g++ -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall -I ../SDL_DekaLib/include -L . -lDeka main.o -o test.exe
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `Log::Get()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `Log::Print(char const*, ...)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `Log::Get()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `Log::~Log()'
```

Теперь библиотека. Она состоит только из логов:

log.h

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdarg>

class Log
    {
    public:
        Log();
        ~Log();

        static Log* Get();
        void Print(const char* message, ...);
        void Debug(const char* message, ...);
        void Error(const char* message, ...);
    private:
        static Log* _instance;
        FILE* _file;

        void _print(const char* lvltext, const char* message);
        void _init();
        void _close();
    };
```

log.cpp - реализацию убрал, ибо не должна влиять на проблему, надеюсь.

```
#include "log.h"

Log* Log::_instance = nullptr;

void Log::_init()
    {
        ...
    }
void Log::_close()
    {
        ...
    }
Log::Log() : _file(nullptr)
    {
        _init();
    }
Log::~Log()
    {
        _close();
        _instance = nullptr;
    }
Log* Log::Get()
    {
        if(!Log::_instance)
            Log::_instance = new Log();

        return Log::_instance;
    }
void Log::Print(const char* message, ...)
    {
        ...
    }
void Log::Debug(const char* message, ...)
    {
#ifdef DEBUG

        ...

#endif // DEBUG
    }
void Log::Error(const char* message, ...)
    {
        ...
    }

    void Log::_print(const char* lvltext, const char* message)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Судя по `system("pause");` дело происходит еще и в винде?

Comment: Да. Это как-то мешает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо немного порядок поменять:
Было:

```
all: main.o libDeka.a
    $(LINK) $(LINKFLAGS) main.o -o test.exe
```

Стало:

```
all: main.o libDeka.a
    $(LINK) main.o $(LINKFLAGS) -o test.exe
```

А еще лучше:

```
all: main.o libDeka.a
    $(LINK) -o test.exe main.o $(LINKFLAGS)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Никогда бы не догадался до такого.

Answer (score 0):

Есть мысль, что библиотека `Deka` просто не пересобирается, а основной модуль ссылается на некоторую пустышку, в которой ещё нет реализации. Убедитесь, что `libDeka.a` обновляется и что именно обновлённый файл линкер использует при сборке `main`.

Для упрощения поиска проблемы я бы предложил исключить лишние функции, библиотеки и избавиться от пространства имён. Короче говоря попытайтесь создать [Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Проверьте, что проблемы не возникает, если отказаться от использования библиотеки и ограничиться одним *Makefile*, где прописано правило сборки `log.o` в составе единого модуля. Примерно так:

```
all: main.o log.o
    $(LINK) $(LINKFLAGS) main.o log.o -o test.exe 

...
```

Дополнительно можете ознакомиться с вопросом: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Comment: Скомпилировав вместе с log.o обнаружилась ошибка: я не определил Log::_instance. После исправления всё успешно собралось и запустилось.
Чтобы удостоверится в отсутствии "пустышки" я удалил библиотеку и скомпилировал заново. Ошибка так и осталась.
Меня также напрягает в логах undefined reference to `DEKA_SDL::Log::Print(char const*, ...), а не undefined reference to `DEKA_SDL::Log::Print(const char*, ...)

Comment: @DeucalionMachine попробуйте убрать всё лишнее из кода, создав [mcve].

Comment: Сделал данный пример [ссылка](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zczlmotz56rspk/LogError.zip?dl=0)