# Подключение класса и создание бинарника

Tags: c++, linux

Добрый день! такая проблема, не могу подключить класс и создать бинарник.

```
test.h
#ifndef _test_h_
#define _test_h_

class test
{
    public:
        test ();
        void show();

    private:

};

#endif
```

```
test.cpp
#include "test.h"
#include 


test::test(){}

void test::show(){
    std::cout
```

```
main.cpp
#include "test.h"


int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    test t();
    t.show();
    return 0;
}
```

**g++ -o bin main.cpp** 
выводит
/tmp/ccmd32Df.o: In function main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference totest::test()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `test::show()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с проблемой [подробнее](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы компилируете только `main.cpp`, но не `test.cpp`, и соответсвенно при компоновке компоновщик не находит функцию `test::test()`, о чем вам и сообщает. По хорошему вы должны скомпилировать каждый `.cpp` файл в объектный файл (`main.cpp -> main.o`), если только `.cpp` файл никуда не подключается через `#include`, и потом все объектные файлы слинковать в исполняемый. То есть в вашем случае команды будут выглядеть так:

```
$ gcc -c main.cpp -o main.o # -c говорит GCC создать из файла исходного кода объектный файл
$ gcc -c test.cpp -o test.o
$ gcc main.o test.o -o bin
```

Или можно сразу передать компилятору все `.cpp` файлы и он сам все сделает:

```
$ gcc main.cpp test.cpp -o bin
```