# Проблема подключения ffmpeg в visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ffmpeg

Я, вроде бы, подключил к VS ffmpeg, но при компиляции возникает ошибка:

> error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_av_register_all"

Так вот тут либо я подключил все криво, или уже не знаю что.

Мне нужна помощь:

1. Нужна подробная пошаговая инструкция по установке ffmpeg(на русском, я в англ не алё).
2. И что это за ошибка?

Comment: А как это вы подключили к VS ffmpeg? Сторонние библиотеки подключают к проекту программы, которую вы пишете через References. Или используют установку пакетов Nuget.

Comment: да, подключил к проекту. И возникает такая проблема.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с [вопросом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217) о причинах ошибки. Подробную инструкцию вряд ли кто тут будет писать. Если у Вас есть ссылка на английскую, приведите её в вопросе, возможно основные моменты кто-то поможет Вам понять.

Comment: Спасибо, почитал и меня осенило))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему!!!

Была полезна ссылка alexolut-а: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Я создавал проект: "Консольное приложение Win32", а подключал библиотеку 64-х разрядную. Вот поэтому, как мне кажется, у меня возникали ошибки. Кароче, скачал 32-х разрядную версию ffmpeg, поставил вместо 64-х разрядной. Рецепт: скачать ffmpeg-dev и ffmpeg-shared 32-х разрядные, из dev подключил include-ы и lib-ы, а из shared взял dll-ки и закинул в SysWOW64. И все заработало.