# Проблема с OpenCV - undefined reference

Tags: c++, opencv, mingw

Решил изучить OpenCV... Собрал статические библиотеки под MinGW, попробовал запустить простой код [отсюда](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2013/06/load-display-image.html) - и получил кучу undefined reference-ов:

```
g++ -m32    -o dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/testopencv build/Release/MinGW-Windows/TestOpenCV.o -L/D/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib -lopencv_core320 -lopencv_highgui320
build/Release/MinGW-Windows/TestOpenCV.o:TestOpenCV.cpp:(.text.startup+0x40): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_core320.a(persistence.cpp.obj):persistence.cpp:(.text$_ZL12icvCloseFileP13CvFileStorage+0x4b): undefined reference to `gzclose'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_core320.a(persistence.cpp.obj):persistence.cpp:(.text$_ZL6icvEofP13CvFileStorage+0x3e): undefined reference to `gzeof'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_core320.a(persistence.cpp.obj):persistence.cpp:(.text$_ZL7icvPutsP13CvFileStoragePKc+0x1f7): undefined reference to `gzputs'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_core320.a(persistence.cpp.obj):persistence.cpp:(.text$_ZL7icvGetsP13CvFileStoragePci+0xe0): undefined reference to `gzgets'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_core320.a(persistence.cpp.obj):persistence.cpp:(.text$cvOpenFileStorage+0xe4f): undefined reference to `gzrewind'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_core320.a(persistence.cpp.obj):persistence.cpp:(.text$cvOpenFileStorage+0x170e): undefined reference to `gzopen'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL15icvRemoveWindowP8CvWindow+0x11b): undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL15icvRemoveWindowP8CvWindow+0x126): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL15icvRemoveWindowP8CvWindow+0x138): undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL16icvGetBitmapDataP8CvWindowP7tagSIZEPiPPv.isra.0+0x1e): undefined reference to `GdiFlush@0'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL16icvGetBitmapDataP8CvWindowP7tagSIZEPiPPv.isra.0+0x32): undefined reference to `GetCurrentObject@8'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL16icvGetBitmapDataP8CvWindowP7tagSIZEPiPPv.isra.0+0x6d): undefined reference to `GetObjectA@12'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL14MainWindowProcP6HWND__jjl+0x2b2): undefined reference to `CreateRectRgn@16'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL14MainWindowProcP6HWND__jjl+0x2db): undefined reference to `CreateRectRgn@16'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL14MainWindowProcP6HWND__jjl+0x304): undefined reference to `CreateRectRgn@16'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL14MainWindowProcP6HWND__jjl+0x322): undefined reference to `CombineRgn@16'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL14MainWindowProcP6HWND__jjl+0x339): undefined reference to `CombineRgn@16'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL14MainWindowProcP6HWND__jjl+0x373): undefined reference to `FillRgn@12'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL14MainWindowProcP6HWND__jjl+0x37e): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL14MainWindowProcP6HWND__jjl+0x389): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL14MainWindowProcP6HWND__jjl+0x394): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x2d9): undefined reference to `SetStretchBltMode@8'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x363): undefined reference to `StretchBlt@44'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x3e5): undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleDC@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x438): undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleBitmap@12'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x457): undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x477): undefined reference to `SetStretchBltMode@8'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x4e0): undefined reference to `SetDIBColorTable@16'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x52b): undefined reference to `BitBlt@36'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x542): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x551): undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x5fc): undefined reference to `BitBlt@36'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL11HighGUIProcP6HWND__jjl+0x74f): undefined reference to `SetDIBColorTable@16'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL14showSaveDialogP8CvWindow+0x104): undefined reference to `GetSaveFileNameA@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$_ZL14showSaveDialogP8CvWindow+0x483): undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$cvInitSystem+0x8f): undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$cvInitSystem+0xc3): undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$cvNamedWindow+0x204): undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleDC@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$cvShowImage+0x10b): undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$cvShowImage+0x116): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$cvShowImage+0x1a7): undefined reference to `CreateDIBSection@24'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$cvShowImage+0x1b9): undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$cvShowImage+0x213): undefined reference to `cvConvertImage'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$cvShowImage+0x2a1): undefined reference to `cvConvertImage'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$cvShowImage+0x2c1): undefined reference to `cvConvertImage'
d:/Programms/MinGW/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui320.a(window_w32.cpp.obj):window_w32.cpp:(.text$cvShowImage+0x374): undefined reference to `cvConvertImage'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/testopencv.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/d/Projects/TestOpenCV'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Projects/TestOpenCV'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Библиотеки:
[image: Libs]
Вроде статические библиотеки... Пробовал линковать всё, что есть в папке с библиотеками. Может я что-то не так подключил или собрал? Чего ему не хватает?

Comment: Добавьте следующие библиотеки при линковке; **libz.a (libzlib.a)**, **libgdi32.a**, **libcomdlg32.a**, **libopencv_imgcodecs320.a**, **libopencv_imgproc320.a**.

Comment: Ещё больше undefined reference, все связаны с opencv_imgproc320 и opencv_imgcodecs320

Comment: Поскольку эти библиотеки работают с изображениями, то скорей всего они требуют линковки с liblibpng, liblibjpeg и т.д . Из сообщения об ошибке `undefined reference to 'xxx'` вполне можно понять какие библиотеки требуются. В крайнем случае, можно воспользоваться утилитой `nm.exe`(она идёт в комплекте с MinGW) и посмотреть что экспортируется из каждой конкретной библиотеки.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с [вопросом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217) для понимания причин.