# undefined reference to `_imp__ntohs@4'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Собственно говоря вводя функцию ntohs(3); в qt получаю ошибку `undefined reference to '_imp__ntohs@4'` Хотя ctrl+пробел эту функцию показывает подключал все эти вещи: `<Windows.h>`, `#include <WinSock2.h>`, `#include <winsock2.h>`,`#include <w32api.h>`,`#include <vector>`,`#include <stdlib.h>`,`#include <winsock.h>`   толку 0

Comment: А библиотеку подключить? Уточните ОС заодно...

Comment: сразу после этих инклудов добавьте `#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")` отдельной строкой

Comment: Windows 10 Строка не помогла. Может в pro файле что нибудь написать?

Comment: А Вы случано не mingw компилируете? строка выше подходит для студийного компилятора. но можно попробовать универсально - добавить `LIBS += -lws2_32` в pro файл

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с [общими причинами](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Comment: Ну у меня вот эти компиляторы в каталог сборки стоят build-RemotePcServers-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug и build-RemotePcServers-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug + последний с воскл знаком еще стоял 5.6 я его убрал.

Comment: Спс #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") походу вот это помогло. Наверно поставлю в ответ.