# VC++. Ошибки LNK2019, LNK1120. Проблема с классом

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++

Имею такие две ошибки. VC++ 2015.
Я так понимаю ошибка касаться класса, но не могу понять в чем именно проблема.

Ошибка  1

> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public:
>   __thiscall Employee1::Employee1(int,int,int)" (??0Employee1@@QAE@HHH@Z) в функции
>   _main C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Исходный
>   код.obj   test

Ошибка  2

> error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов:
>   1 C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\test.exe  test

Вот код:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

class Employee1
{
public:
    Employee1 (int Age, int YOS, int Sal);
    ~Employee1 () {}
    void SetAge(int Age) {age = Age;}
    void SetYOS(int YOS) {yearsOfService = YOS;}
    void SetSalary(int Sal) {Salary = Sal;}

    int GetAge() const {return age;}
    int GetYOS() const {return yearsOfService;}
    int GetSalary() const {return Salary;}
private:
    int age;
    int yearsOfService;
    int Salary;
};

int main()
{
Employee1 asdfask(12,12,12);
Employee1 sadasdfasdf(12,12,12);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте определение конструктора

Comment: Спасибо большое. Собственно это и решило мою проблему. "Employee1 (int Age, int YOS, int Sal) {}"

Comment: подумайте еще над определением конструктора. Это только решило проблему линковки

Comment: [Ознакомьтесь с причинами ошибки.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217)