# Проблема с использованием шаблона класса в C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Возникла проблема при написании шаблонного класса, в его методе test вызывается метод другого класса, при компиляции получаю ошибку

> undefined reference to `bar::printHello()'

В чем может быть проблема?

**main.cpp**

```
#include<main.h>
#include <foo.h>

int main(){
    foo<int> _fo ;
    _fo.test();
    return 0;
}
```

**main.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <bar.h>
```

**foo.h**

```
#pragma once
#include<bar.h>
template<class T>
class foo{
public:
    foo(){
    }

   void  test(){
      bar b;
      b.printHello();
    }
};
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
```

#### bar.h

```
#pragma once
class bar
{
public:
    bar();
    void printHello();
};
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "bar.h"
#include <iostream>
bar::bar()
{
}

void printHello(){
    std::cout<<"Hello";
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не пробовали переписать

```
void printHello(){
    std::cout<<"Hello";
}
```

как

```
void bar::printHello(){
    std::cout<<"Hello";
}
```

?
Т.е. пояснить, что это не просто свободная функция `printHello`, а член класса `bar`?

Comment: Пробовал, получал `extra qualification 'bar::' on member 'printHello' ` что по моему логично, ведь она в public'e этого класса, что явно указывает что она его член.

Comment: Где вы это написали? В `bar.cpp`? Либо перенесите определение `printHello` в объявление `bar`, либо в определении `printHello` добавьте, какому классу она принадлежит.

Comment: Затупил, писал в bar.h, добавил void bar::printHello() в bar.cpp и проблема решилась, благодарю.