# Шаблонный класс

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте,помогите пожалуйста.Пытаюсь реализовать шаблонный класс с шаблонными функциями. Не понимаю в чем ошибка при компиляции, подскажите пожалуйста:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   Stack::Push(float)" (?Push@?$Stack@M@@QAEXM@Z) referenced in
>   function _main    Calc

и

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall
>   Stack::Pop(void)" (?Pop@?$Stack@M@@QAEMXZ) referenced in
>   function _main    Calc

Код(header):

```
#pragma once

template <class T>
struct Element
{
    T data;
    Element<T>* next;
};


///////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    Element<T>* Head;
public:
    Stack<T>() {}
    ~Stack<T>() {}
    void Push(T d);
    T Pop();
};
```

Определение методов:

```
 #include "Stack.h"

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::Push(T d)
{
    Element* new_Element = new Element;
    new_Element->data = d;
    new_Element->next = Head;
    Head = new_Element;
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::Pop()
{
    T temp = Head->data;
    Element *new_Element = Head;
    Head = Head->next;
    delete new_Element;
    return temp;
}
```

И `main ()`:

```
 #include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>



int main()
{
    Stack<float> s;

    int n;
    int value;

    std::cout << "How many values will you have?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> value;

    for (int i(0); i < value; i++)
    {
        std::cout << " Enter number: ";
        std::cin >> n;
        s.Push(n);
    }

     while (true);
    {

        std::cout << "Enter symbol (space for exit):";
        int choice = getchar();
        switch (choice)
        {
        case '+':
            s.Push(s.Pop() + s.Pop());
            break;
        case '-':
            s.Push(-s.Pop() + s.Pop());
            break;
        case '*':
            s.Push(s.Pop()*s.Pop());
            break;
        case '/':
            s.Push(s.Pop() / s.Pop());
        /*case '=':
            std::cout <<"Result: "<< s.Pop()<<std::endl;
            break;*/
        case ' ':
            exit(-1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема......

Comment: Реализация шаблонных функций должна быть в заголовочном файле. См. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Comment: Кажется, это самый популярный вопрос по крайней мере на русском SO.

Comment: @int3 +1. все мы через это проходили