# VSC++ ошибка LNK2019 при подключении библиотеки

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, компоновщик

При подключении написанной мной библиотеки Library.dll в проект возникают ошибки

> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __thiscall Contact::PhoneNumber(void)"
>   (?PhoneNumber@Contact@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
>   в функции _main   Лабораторная работа
>   4-8   \mac\Home\Documents\Университет\Операционные системы\Лабораторная
>   работа 4-8\Лабораторная работа 4-8\Лабораторная работа 4-8.obj    1
>
> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __thiscall Contact::Name(void)"
>   (?Name@Contact@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
>   в функции _main   Лабораторная работа
>   4-8   \mac\Home\Documents\Университет\Операционные системы\Лабораторная
>   работа 4-8\Лабораторная работа 4-8\Лабораторная работа 4-8.obj    1

Library.h:

```
#ifdef LIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"
#include <string>
#include "Contact.h"
#include <algorithm>


//Минимально возможное значение хеша
static const size_t min_hash_value = 48;
// Максимально возможное значение хеша
static const size_t max_hash_value = 122;
// Размер хеш-таблицы
static const size_t ht_size = 74;

list<Contact> hashtable[ht_size];

__declspec(dllexport) void Add(string, string);
__declspec(dllexport) bool Delete(string);
__declspec(dllexport) string FindContact(string);
__declspec(dllexport) list<Contact> GetContacts(int);
__declspec(dllexport) void WriteToFile(HANDLE);
__declspec(dllexport) void ReadFromFile(HANDLE);

size_t GetHashCode(Contact);
size_t GetHashCode(string);
```

Лабораторная работа 4-8.cpp:

```
// Лабораторная работа 4-6.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "Library.h"
#include "Contact.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");

    string name, phonenumber;

    HANDLE File = CreateFile(TEXT("Z:/Desktop/File.txt"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    ReadFromFile(File);
    CloseHandle(File);

    string menu;

    while (menu != "0")
    {
        system("cls");

        cout << "Список контактов:" << endl << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 74; i++)
        {
            list<Contact> list = GetContacts(i);

            for each (Contact C in list)
            {
                cout << C.Name() << ": " << C.PhoneNumber() << endl;
            }
        }

        cout << endl << "Выберите действие:" << endl << "1 - Добавить контакт" << endl << "2 - Удалить контакт" << endl << "3 - Поиск контакта по имени" << endl << "0 - Выход\t\t";
        getline(cin, menu);

        if (menu == "1")
        {
            cout << endl << "Введите имя контакта: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            if (name != "")
            {
                cout << "Введите номер телефона: ";
                getline(cin, phonenumber);

                if (phonenumber != "") Add(name, phonenumber);

                else
                {
                    cout << "Ошибка!" << endl << "Необходимо ввести телефонный номер" << endl;
                    system("PAUSE");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Ошибка!" << endl << "Необходимо ввести имя контакта" << endl;
                system("PAUSE");
            }
        }
        else if (menu == "2")
        {
            cout << endl << "Введите имя контакта для удаления: ";
            getline(cin, name);

            if (name != "" && Delete(name));

            else
            {
                cout << "Контакт не найден!" << endl;
                system("PAUSE");
            }
        }
        else if (menu == "3")
        {
            cout << endl << "Введите имя контакта для поиска: ";
            getline(cin, name);

            if (name != "") cout << "Номер телефона: " << FindContact(name) << endl;

            else cout << "Контакт не найден!" << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
    }

    File = CreateFile(TEXT("Z:/Desktop/File.txt"), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    WriteToFile(File);

    CloseHandle(File);

    return 0;
}
```

На всякий случай Contact.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Contact  // Содержит имя контакта и телефонный номер
{
private:
    string name;
    string phonenumber;
public:
    string Name();  // Имя контакта
    string PhoneNumber();   // Телефонный номер
    Contact(string, string);
    bool operator==(string);
};
```

Причем, если закомментить эту часть

```
    for each (Contact C in list)
    {
        cout << C.Name() << ": " << C.PhoneNumber() << endl;
    }
```

То ошибки пропадают. Как я понял, ругается на string...

Comment: Ознакомиться с возможными причинами ошибки можно [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Answer (score 0):

Нашлась проблема. Не было доступа к C.Name() и C.PhoneNumber().
Сделал поля public и через прямой доступ к ним все заработало.