# Как исправить ошибку undefined reference to

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake

Мне нужно использовать готовый C++ класс Catalog. Используя [статью](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#new-project) сделал начальную настройку проекта. `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        tv.setText("C++ bool = " + getTestBool());
    }

    public native boolean getTestBool();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(
             native-lib
             SHARED
             native-lib.cpp )

add_library(
             catalog
             SHARED
             catalog.cpp )

find_library(
              log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries(
                       native-lib
                       ${log-lib} )

target_link_libraries(
                       catalog
                       ${log-lib} )

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

native-lib.cpp:

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include "string.h"

#include "catalog.h"

extern "C"//При експорте функций имена их не будут изменятся
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_ru_artem_ndktest2_MainActivity_getTestBool(
        JNIEnv *env, //указатель на объект, представляющий из себя JNI-окружение
        jobject) { //класс, которому принадлежит объявление нативного метода в Java. Фактически это this)

    Catalog cat;
    return cat.getResult();
}
```

catalog.h:

```
#ifndef DBADAPTER_H
#define DBADAPTER_H

#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#define DISABLE_SEARCH_BY_WORD

class Catalog
{

    public : //slots
        bool getResult();
};


#endif // DBADAPTER_H
```

catalog.cpp:

```
#include "catalog.h"

using namespace std;

bool Catalog::getResult() {
    return true;
}
```

Но получаю ошибку при вызове метода find:

> Error:(27) undefined reference to `Catalog::getResult()'

Как её исправить? [Ссылка](https://github.com/iamtihonov/NDKTest2) на весь мини проект.

**UPD** 
Упростил и добавил дополнительный код

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217) читали?

Comment: @alexolut спасибо за ссылку, но ни одной из ошибок в проекте я не вижу.

Comment: Постарайтесь уменьшить код до состояния [mcve]. В текущем виде всё, что можно сказать, это то, что реализация `Catalog::find(int)` не видна.

Comment: @упростил и добавил

Comment: Что-то я не вижу и в исправленных текстах в вопросе реализации `Catalog::find(int)`

Comment: @avp поправил вопрос

Comment: Нет линковки `nativ-lib` с `catalog`. Отсюда и ошибка при линковке `nativ-lib` - реализация `Catalog::getResult()` ей не видна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю на сколько верно я сделал, но все файлы отлично подключились следующей командой в *CMakeList*:

```
add_library(
             native-lib
             SHARED
             native-lib.cpp classes/catalog.cpp headers/catalog.h)
```