# qt c++ ошибка undefined reference to

Tags: c++, qt

В отдельном заголовочном файле описываю класс сцены

## scene.h

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#ifndef SCENE_H
#define SCENE_H
class Scene1: public QGraphicsScene{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Scene1(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, b2World *world);
   public slots: void advance(){

    };
 private:
    b2World* world;

};



#endif // SCENE_H
```

Подключаю в

## mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
...   
... 
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
Scene1* scene;
QTimer* frametimer;
b2World* world;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Ошибка возникает при добавлении следующей строчки в

## mainwindow.cpp

```
 scene = new Scene1 (0,0,8,6,world);
```

(пишу ее в конструкторе)без нее все работает

## Сама ошибка

```
debug/mainwindow.o: In function `ZN10MainWindowC2EP7QWidget':
E:\project\simple\test\build-qqq-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_MinGW_32bit-        
Debug/../qqq/mainwindow.cpp:22: undefined reference to 
`Scene1::Scene1(double, double, double, double, b2World*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

"ОЧИСТИТЬ"-"qmake"-"собрать все" я пробовал, эффект нулевой. в чем может быть проблема?

PS
screenshot подсветки кода когда пишу название моего пользовательского класса в mainwindow.cpp, не могу продвинуться дальше не создав его объект(
[image: screenshot подсветки кода когда пишу название класса в mainwindow.cpp]

## проект.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = qqq
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
main.cpp \
mainwindow.cpp\
scene.h

HEADERS += \
mainwindow.h \
Box2D/Box2D.h \
scene.h

FORMS += \
mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY = 

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lBox2D

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/./Box2D.lib
else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/./libBox2D.a
```

Comment: реализация конструктора где?

Comment: У вас линковка не проходит. Приведите содержание `.pro`-файла.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: @aleks.andr, действительно, линковка не проходит, но внешние библиотеки здесь не используются. Поэтому `.pro`-файл здесь не при чём. Скорее всего, просто нет тела конструктора.

Comment: выкладываю .про

Answer (score 0, accepted):

засунул определение класса в данном виде обратно в

## mainwindow.H

```
сlass Scene1: public QGraphicsScene{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Scene1(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, b2World *world);
   public slots: void advance();
 private:
    b2World* world;

};
```

в конце mainwindow.cpp определил класс,входные значения(вызовы функции коэфицента умножения), и определил виртуальную функцию таким образом

## mainwindow.cpp

```
.....
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


Scene1::Scene1(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, b2World *world)

    :QGraphicsScene (fromB2(x),fromB2(y),fromB2(width),fromB2(height))
{
    this->world=world;

}

void Scene1::advance(){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас в `.pro`-файле допущена опечатка:

```
SOURCES += \
main.cpp \
mainwindow.cpp\
scene.h
^^^^^^^
```

Замените `scene.h` на `scene.cpp` в секции `SOURCES`.

А на данный момент ваш файл `scene.cpp` не участвует в компиляции, поэтому линковщик и не видит реализаций функций.

**UPD:**

Если вы сознательно не создаёте файл `scene.cpp`, тогда реализация объявленного вами конструктора класса `Scene1` (как впрочем и других методов) должна быть добавлена в `scene.h`:

```
class Scene1 : public QGraphicsScene
{
    ...

    Scene1(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, b2World *world) :
        QGraphicsScene(x, y, width, height),
        world(world)
    { }

    ...
};
```

И в любом случае -- удалите упоминание `scene.h` из секции `SOURCES` в `.pro`-файле.

Comment: Scene.cpp нету, отдельный заголовочный файл нужен чтобы Q_OBJECT не ругался. В нем я просто описывают класс чтобы в mainwindow.cpp создать его объект и работать с ним(Q_OBJECT тянется из за того что класс наследует public от графической сцены)

Comment: В вашем `scene.h` объявлен конструктор класса `Scene1`. Где определена реализация этого конструктора? Правильно вам линковщик говорит, что её нет.

Answer (score 0):

как минимум, в хедере mainwindow нужно сделать предварительное обьявление класса

```
сlass Scene1;
```

а в файл реализации

```
#include "scene1.h"
```

Comment: Проблема не в этом. Автор приводит ошибку линковщика. Надо `*.pro`-файл смотреть.

Comment: в хедере mainwindow добавил сlass Scene1; в файле реализации "scene1.h" подключен. ошибка та же

Comment: добавил .pro в конец описания