# Undefined reference to `glewInit'

Tags: c++, opengl

Работаю с Opengl, ubuntu 16.04. Хочу скомпилировать пример работы с шейдерами, но на этапе компиляции выдает ошибку:

```
g++ -std=c++11 lab7.cpp -lglfw -lGL -lglut -o lab7
/tmp/ccS6I7iu.o: In function `main':
lab7.cpp:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `glewExperimental'
lab7.cpp:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `glewInit'
```

Возможно, я упустил какой-то флаг, подключающий нужную библиотеку, пробовал флаг -lglfw3, но выдает ошибку о не нахождении такого.

В lab7.cpp подключаю такие библиотеки:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
```

Comment: а разве glew не должно линковаться как `-lGLEW` ?

Comment: Только это уже этап линковки, а не компиляции. Вероятно, Вам поможет комментарий от @Flowneee.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь ещё с вопросом о [undefined reference](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Comment: @Flowneee спасибо, помогло. А есть где-то информация о том, для каких библиотек какие флаги требуется?

Comment: @NEO давайте я сейчас в ответ напишу, чтобы другим не пришлось искать ответ в комментариях.

Comment: @NEO обновил ответ, чтобы ответить и на вопрос из комментариев.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо прилинковать библиотеку libGLEW (флаг gcc `-lGLEW`). В вашем случае команда будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
g++ -std=c++11 lab7.cpp -lglfw -lGL -lglut -lGLEW -o lab7
```

Собственно об этом факте можно прочитать в документации к GLEW:  http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html

**PS**

Как правило, какие флаги нужны для какой библиотеки, указано в документации к библиотеке. Ну или можно просто посмотреть как называется файл библиотеки и указать его имя без приставки lib и расширения, то есть для lib**GLEW**.so будет интересовать часть GLEW, ну и так далее. Посмотрите [тут](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/Link-Options.html), как работает опция `-l`.