# Qt: Ошибка ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__RegOpenKeyExW@20 в функции _main

Tags: c++, qt

Ощибка: main.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__RegOpenKeyExW@20 в функции _main
Что может быть не так? Компилятор MSVC2015 32, на mingw все работает, но мне нужен компилятор MSVC именно Вот код:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "shobjidl.h"

#include "windows.h"
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>
enum HKEY_LIST
{
HK_CLASSES_ROOT=0x80000000,
HK_CURRENT_USER=0x80000001,
HK_LOCAL_MACHINE=0x80000002,
HK_USERS=0x80000003,
HK_PERFORMANCE_DATA=0x80000004,
HK_CURRENT_CONFIG=0x80000005
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
   // QString myValue;

    HKEY hKey;
    LPCWSTR val=L"WallPaper";
    LPCWSTR path=L"Control panel\\Desktop";
    HKEY_LIST  list =HKEY_LIST::HK_CURRENT_USER;
    if(RegOpenKeyEx((HKEY)list,path,0,KEY_READ,&hKey)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DWORD dwSize = 512;
        wchar_t lszValue[512];
        bool noError=RegQueryValueEx(hKey,val,NULL,NULL,(LPBYTE)lszValue,&dwSize)==ERROR_SUCCESS;
        //RegCloseKey(hKey);
        if(noError) {
            QString outp = QString::fromWCharArray(lszValue);
            qDebug() <<"outp=" <<outp;
        }
    }
 MainWindow w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: В свойствах проекта добавьте `advapi32.lib` в список библиотек (Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies).

Comment: А можно пжл поподробней куда там добавлять. Не могу найти там Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies. Сюда захожу:Tools-Options в project тоже нет

Comment: https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/build-and-link/vs-4.png

Comment: И как в это окно попасть?

Comment: https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/05/modules-properties.png

Comment: Спс, только я в QTCreator набирал ), я пробовал добовлять в pro файле добавлять, но не работает

Comment: В случае Qt надо добавить в `.pro`-файл строку `LIBS += -ladvapi32`.

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/317064)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка вида «Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ `__imp__имя@число`» означает, что у вас не подключена системная статическая библиотека, содержащая информацию о том, откуда можно импортировать функцию `имя`.

В вашем случае это функция `RegOpenKeyExW()`.

Сначала необходимо узнать, какая именно статическая библиотека нам нужна. Для этого открываем MSDN-документацию по нужной функции (без суффиксов `A` и `W`), ищем внизу раздел «Requirements», а в нём — таблицу с полем «Library»:

[image: Документация по функции RegOpenKeyEx()]

Теперь необходимо добавить библиотеку в свойства проекта.

1. В Visual Studio вам нужен параметр *Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies*:

   [image: Как открыть свойства проекта]
   [image: Как попасть к полю Additional Dependencies]

   Имя библиотеки можно дописывать хоть в начало, хоть в конец. При этом оно должно начинаться с маленькой буквы (несмотря на то, что в MSDN первая буква почему-то большая) и отделяться от других имён точкой с запятой.
2. В Qt Creator с системой сборки qmake вам нужно добавить в файл проекта (`*.pro`) строку вида `LIBS += -lимя`, где `имя` — это имя требуемой статической библиотеки, начинающееся с маленькой буквы и без расширения `.lib`.

Comment: Да добавлял я LIBS += -advapi32  Правда вот это Warning вывелся и та же самая ошибка :-1: warning: LNK4044: нераспознанный параметр "/advapi32"; игнорируется

Comment: @MadokaMagica, LIBS += -**l**advapi32. Вы `l` (маленькая L) перед именем библиотеки пропустили.

Comment: Все равно не работает, с той же ошибкой но библиотеку подкл. спс

Comment: @MadokaMagica, в панели «Compile Output» должна быть напечатанная длинная командная строка со всем параметрами компилятора (начинается на `g++ ...`, вот пример: https://www.ics.com/sites/default/files/pictures/snapshot25.png (внизу окна программы)). Скопируйте её сюда, пожалуйста.

Comment: Все заработало, спс вам большое, незнаю наверно дело было в моей невнимательности, что то не там записал. Почистил проект пересобрал вроде работает.

Comment: @MadokaMagica, а, тогда дело в кэше make-файлов, генерируемых из `.pro` и используемых непосредственно для сборки — Qt довольно плохо отслеживает изменения в файле проекта.