# Почему линковщик не находит реализацию функции wWinMainCRTStartup?

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

При билде проекта получаю такой список ошибок:

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler [project_path]\[some_obj].obj
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol memchr   [project_path]\[some_obj].obj
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol MyFunction   [project_path]\[project_name].obj
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _exit    [project_path]\[project_name].obj
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol wWinMainCRTStartup LINK
LNK1120 5 unresolved externals  [project_name].exe
```

На MSDN нашла вот [это](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f6xx1b1z.aspx). Особо не поняла, как добавить `msvcrt.lib` и `msvcmrt.lib` в дополнительные зависимости компоновщика. Попробовала сделать это так:

> Project->Properties->C++->Linker->Command Line->Additional Options

написала `/NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcmrt.lib`. Но ничего не изменилось. Как решить вот эти однотипные ошибки линковки?

Возможно это важно в решении данного вопроса: проект компилирую как C-код (/TC).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: `/NODEFAULTLIB` предотвращает линковку дефолтных библиотек, а не добавляет их.

Comment: @VTT спасибо, буду сейчас разбираться.