# Как обратиться к динамически созданным элементам?

Tags: c++, qt, наследование

Пытался обратиться к динамически созданному элементу, но не выходит.

*Я их затираю при создании.*

Было два варианта решения этой проблемы, первый это ложить объекты в вектор list, что бы потом к ним, элементам, обращаться.

Первый вариант показался слишком сложным вариантом для меня.

Второй отнаследовать элемент и добавить переменную для счёта элементов после этого обращаться через этот элемент к динамически созданному элементу.

Я пошёл вторым путем.

*--- вот код ---*

**test11.pro**

```
QT       += core gui serialbus widgets concurrent

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test11
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    qdimaniccheckbox.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    qdimaniccheckbox.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QMainWindow>

/* My Includes */
#include  "qdimaniccheckbox.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    int name_chekbox;

    std::map<int, int> ID_map_poz_send; // текущая позиция отправленного сообщения использемого излучателем в текущий момент. (отправка)

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

public slots:
    void start_sending(bool); // принажатии на чекбокс то выполниться этот слот (отправка сообщений)


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    // Создаём виджет, который будет содержать в себе чекбокс
    QWidget *checkBoxWidget = new QWidget();

    qDimanicCheckBox *checkBox = new qDimanicCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс через новый класс

//    QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс
    QHBoxLayout *layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "QDebug"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    name_chekbox =0;
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "on_pushButton_clicked  "  ;

    //-- добавляем чек бокс в таблицу
    checkBoxWidget = new QWidget(); // создаём новый qwidget()
    checkBox = new qDimanicCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету

    connect(checkBox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this, SLOT(start_sending(bool))); // соединение всех чекетов с "действием"  start_sending

    name_chekbox = name_chekbox +1;

//    checkBox->setText(QString::number(666));
    checkBox->setText(QString::number(checkBox->getID()));

    layoutCheckBox->addWidget(checkBox);            // Устанавливаем чекбокс в слой

    layoutCheckBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);  // Отцентровываем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);    // Устанавливаем нулевые отступы

    ui->tW_test->insertRow(ui->tW_test->rowCount());//вводим колич строк (возвращ колич строк)
    ui->tW_test->setCellWidget(ui->tW_test->rowCount()-1, 1,  checkBoxWidget); // добавляем элемент в таблицу (строка, столбец, добавляемый элемент)
    ID_map_poz_send.insert(std::pair<int, int> (name_chekbox, ui->tW_test->rowCount()-1));// записываем расположение элемента в таблице (вектор расположения)

 }

void MainWindow::start_sending(bool Value)
{
//    qDebug() << ID_m                ap_poz_send.
     qDebug() << "start_sending  "  ;
    // когда нажата отрабатывает, отжата то не отрабатывает
    if (Value == true)
    {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks: "<< " TRUE" ;
        qDebug() << "нажата кнопка : " << QString::number(checkBox->getID());
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks:" << " False";
    }
}
```

**Созданный класс для перенаследования элемента QCheckBox.**

**qdimaniccheckbox.h**

```
#ifndef QDIMANICCHECKBOX_H
#define QDIMANICCHECKBOX_H
#include <QtWidgets>

#include <QCheckBox>

class qDimanicCheckBox : public QCheckBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit qDimanicCheckBox(QWidget *parent =0);
    ~qDimanicCheckBox();

    static int ResID;   // Статическая переменная, счетчик номеров чекбокса
    int getID();        // Функция для возврата локального номера чекбокса

public slots:

private:
    int checkBoxID =0; // Локальная переменная, номер чекбокса
};

#endif // QDIMANICCHECKBOX_H
```

**qdimaniccheckbox.cpp**

```
#include "qdimaniccheckbox.h"

qDimanicCheckBox::qDimanicCheckBox(QWidget *parent) :
    QCheckBox(parent)
{
    ResID++;            // Увеличение счетчика на единицу
    checkBoxID = ResID;   /* Присвоение кнопке номера, по которому будет производиться
                         * дальнейшая работа с кнопок
                         * */
}
qDimanicCheckBox::~qDimanicCheckBox()
{

}

int qDimanicCheckBox::getID()
{
    return checkBoxID;
}

/* Инициализация статической переменной класса.
 * Статическая переменная класса должна инициализироваться в обязательном порядке
 * */
int qDimanicCheckBox::ResID = 0;
```

Я хочу получить надпись "нажата кнопка  9", но я получаю "нажата кнопка 12" по последнему созданному элементу.

Как получить действие нажатого элемента ????

Делал про примеру сделанном на этом [сайте.](https://evileg.com/ru/post/77/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

П.С. ни одного вменяемого элемента 
*создание динамического элемента через QList* нету

Comment: Ошибки говорят о том, что нужно тело деструктора `qDimanicCheckBox::~ qDimanicCheckBox`

Comment: @teivaz спасибо :3

Comment: Так-то казалось бы, первый вариант проще, чем костылить сабкласс

Comment: @BeardedBeaver я не умею, а примеров в интернете нету :( , вот и приходиться "изгаляться ".

Comment: Не стоит постить текст ошибок картинкой. Кроме того, заголовок вопроса ни разу не соответствует ошибки...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: @VTT соответствует, человек захочет разобраться, а примера нет, пичально

Comment: @timob256 в интернете нет примеров добавления указателя на объект в QList? Не верю! (с)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил проблему через qlist.

*--- вот код ----*

**фаил.ui тот же самый**

**фаил.pro тот же самый (только без двух файлов qdimaniccheckbox.h qdimaniccheckbox.cpp)**

**main.cpp тот же самый**

**mainwindows.h**

```
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

public slots:
    void start_sending(bool); // принажатии на чекбокс то выполниться этот слот (отправка сообщений)


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QList<QCheckBox*> test_checkbox;  // вот вектор
    QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();
    // Создаём виджет, который будет содержать в себе чекбокс
    QWidget *checkBoxWidget = new QWidget();
    // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету
    QHBoxLayout *layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindows.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    test_checkbox.clear();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    test_checkbox.clear();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //-- добавляем чек бокс в таблицу
    checkBoxWidget = new QWidget(); // создаём новый qwidget()
    checkBox = new QCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету
    test_checkbox.append(checkBox);
    connect(checkBox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this, SLOT(start_sending(bool))); // соединение всех чекетов с "действием"  start_sending

    checkBox->setText(QString::number(666));

    layoutCheckBox->addWidget(checkBox);            // Устанавливаем чекбокс в слой

    layoutCheckBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);  // Отцентровываем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);    // Устанавливаем нулевые отступы

    ui->tW_test->insertRow(ui->tW_test->rowCount());//вводим колич строк (возвращ колич строк)
    ui->tW_test->setCellWidget(ui->tW_test->rowCount()-1, 1,  checkBoxWidget); // добавляем элемент в таблицу (строка, столбец, добавляемый элемент)
 }

void MainWindow::start_sending(bool Value)
{
      qDebug() << "start_sending  "  ;
    // когда нажата отрабатывает, отжата то не отрабатывает
    if (Value == true)
    {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks: "<< " TRUE" ;
         qDebug() << "test_checkbox: "<<test_checkbox.length();
        for (int i =0 ;i < test_checkbox.length();i++ )
        {
            if(test_checkbox[i]->isChecked() ==Value)
                qDebug() << "вот через вектор qlist  :" << i;
        }
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks:" << " False";
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*п.с. я очень расстроился из за того что мне так и не помогли.*