# Найти и описать ошибку в коде с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

у меня есть код на с++, нужно найти в чем заключается ошибка, описать ее, и по возможности исправить:)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>

using namespace std;

class stack
{
  public:
  stack(int size);
  void push(int d );
  int pop();
   };

  int main()
  {
   setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUSSIAN");

   stack a(10);

   a.push(1);
   a.push(2);
   a.push(3);
   a.push(4);
   a.push(5);

   cout << a.pop() << ' ';
   cout << a.pop() << ' ';
   cout << a.pop() << ' ';
   cout << a.pop() << endl;
   }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Ну что, функция main в классе...

Comment: @MrBin Плохое форматирование, которое вас заставило так думать - да, но `main` не в классе...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: @Harry, Точно. Ошибочка вышла

Answer (score 5):

У вас есть *создаваемый вами* класс `stack`, с которым вы работаете. Вы указали компилятору, что у него есть конструктор и функции-члены `pop` и `push`. Компилятор принял это к сведению.

Вы использовали все три в программе. Компилятор не возражал - вы же объявили, что они есть (будут), он скомпилировал, написав в объектных файлах что-то вроде (в переводе на человеческий язык) - "компоновщик, тут вызов функции `stack::pop`, возьми его сам знаешь откуда, и подставь".

Компоновщик рад стараться. Он ищет эти функции везде - в каждом файле, *который ему передан для компоновки* (но вы передали только один, с приведенным текстом), в библиотеках - но ничего не находит. Потому что вы не озаботились написать *определения* (*реализации*) этих функций. И никто не знает, что вы хотели в них написать - может, функция `pop` должна выводить на экран мультик... А делать что-либо без команды ни компилятор, ни компоновщик не приучены.

Ну, и жалуется компоновщик на отсутствие ваших функций, как умеет - что (в переводе) встретил неразрешенный символ, на который есть ссылка в функции `main`...

Comment: Спасибо, про реализацию функций совсем забыл, благодарю еще раз)

Answer (score 1):

У вас либо отсутствует реализация класса `stack`, либо вы хотели подключить `std::stack`, но забыли включить заголовочный файл

```
#include <stack>
```

Я склоняюсь к первому.