# LNK2001, FTP Client, C++

Tags: c++

Делал крупный для себя проект, и часто встречался с ошибками LNK2005, LNK2001, но с легкостью их решал ибо они были с перменными, однако тут проблема которую я решить не смогу, нагуглить не смог, решил обратится, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

FTP.cpp:

```
#include "Incl.h"
#include "Get.h"
#define HOST ""
#define LOG ""
#define PASS ""
#define DIR ""

char host[256];
HINTERNET internet;
HINTERNET ftp_session;

void FTPLog()
{
    strcpy(host, HOST);
    internet = InternetOpenA(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    ftp_session = InternetConnectA(internet, host, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, LOG, PASS, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
    FtpPutFileA(ftp_session, buffer, buffer, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
    FtpSetCurrentDirectoryA(ftp_session, DIR);
    InternetCloseHandle(ftp_session);
    InternetCloseHandle(internet);
}
```

Get.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#pragma once
extern TCHAR exepath[MAX_PATH];
extern char dir[FILENAME_MAX];
extern int keycountclear;
extern char buffer[80];
extern void GetPathK();
extern void GetTimeK();
extern void GetKeyK();
extern void DropFile();
extern void RemoveOld();
extern void FTPsend();
```

Incl.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <direct.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#pragma once
```

Ошибки:

```
1>FTP.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__FtpSetCurrentDirectoryA@8"
1>FTP.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__InternetOpenA@20"
1>FTP.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__InternetCloseHandle@4"
1>FTP.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__FtpPutFileA@20"
1>FTP.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__InternetConnectA@32"
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было подключить Wininet.lib