# Как компилировать на Linux и на Windows одновременно, используя CMake?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cmake, кросс-компиляция

Я пишу всё с Linux-а, и все проекты, соответственно, собираются исключительно под Linux.
Недавно я нашёл, что с помощью MinGW можно компелировать с Линукса проекты на винду. Попробовал `"Hello, World!"` - проверил - получилось. Это меня обрадовало. Попробовал немножечко переделать один из своих давних проектов, который использовал несколько сторонних библиотек, и вот тут начались трудности.

Очевидно, что для Windows пойдут только соответствующие библиотеки. Скачал, вроде всё правильно настроил в CMake-е, но... Любимый `undefined  reference` встретил меня с улыбкой.

Мой CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(DiSqProj)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


if (false) # Unix

    message("Building project for Unix.")

    set(LIBS
        -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw
        -lsfml-graphics
        -lsfml-window
        -lsfml-system)

elseif(true) # Win64

    message("Building project for Win64.")

    set(WIN_LIBS_DIR
        /home/prunkles/Dev/CLionProjects/WinLibs)

    set(INCLUDE_DIRS
        PUBLIC ${WIN_LIBS_DIR}/glew-2.1.0/include # GLEW include
        PUBLIC ${WIN_LIBS_DIR}/glfw-3.2.1/include # GLFW include
        PUBLIC ${WIN_LIBS_DIR}/SFML-2.5.0/include # SFML include
        PUBLIC ${WIN_LIBS_DIR}/glm/include # GLM include
    )

    set(LINK_DIRS
        ${WIN_LIBS_DIR}/glew-2.1.0/lib/Release/x64 # GLEW lib
        ${WIN_LIBS_DIR}/glfw-3.2.1/lib-mingw-w64 # GLFW lib
        ${WIN_LIBS_DIR}/SFML-2.5.0/lib # SFML lib
    )

    set(LIBS
        glew32s
        glfw3
        sfml-graphics
        sfml-window
        sfml-system
    )

endif()

link_directories(${LINK_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
    DiamondSquare.cpp DiamondSquare.h
    rand-adv.h
    inWin3D.cpp
    inWin2D.cpp inFiles.cpp
    ViewTypes.h
    genImageFromMap.cpp genImageFromMap.h
    Camera.cpp Camera.h
    GLLoadShaders.h)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${LIBS})
```

Comment: А те сторонние библиотеки случайно не для Microsoft Visual Studio собраны? Там другие правила декорирования (mangling) экспортируемых C++-имён, отличные от таковых у GCC.

Comment: @Arhad Хм, вполне возможно. Но как с этим бороться, если нет собранных либ для gcc?

Comment: @Arhad Могу ли я скачать исходники и собрать библиотеку сам? В таком случае, это уже точно нужно делать с Windows, да?

Comment: Если вы скачиваете исходники, собирать их надо тем же инструментарием, что и вашу программу. Тогда, во-первых, автоматом сойдутся соглашения вызовов и правила декорирования, а во-вторых, сформируется зависимость от одной и той же runtime-библиотеки C++. То есть если вы собираете под Linux-овым портом MinGW, то и библиотеку надо собирать там же.

Comment: А что за if (false)? Подписано как unix в комментарии, но как cmake это определяет то?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Никак, просто сделал так, для теста

Comment: "undefined reference", говорите ... собственно, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведённый Вами пример плох тем, что в нём явно указаны библиотеки и хедеры, которые, вообще говоря, зависят от платформы. Не надо так делать. Используемые Вами библиотеки имеют или [поставляют сами](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/cmake/SFMLConfig.cmake.in#L10) описания для их сборки/подключения в проект в виде так называемого пакета, который следует подключить с помощью [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html).

Вначале как обычно:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(DiSqProj)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

Затем ищем зависимости:

```
find_package(OpenGL)
find_package(GLEW)
```

С этими пакетами все хорошо, они есть в самом CMake, а вот с [GLFW оказалось не так просто - не `find_package(GLFW)`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build.html)

```
find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)
find_package(SFML COMPONENTS graphics window system)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
    DiamondSquare.cpp DiamondSquare.h
    rand-adv.h
    inWin3D.cpp
    inWin2D.cpp inFiles.cpp
    ViewTypes.h
    genImageFromMap.cpp genImageFromMap.h
    Camera.cpp Camera.h
    GLLoadShaders.h)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    OpenGL::OpenGL GLEW::GLEW glfw
    sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)
```

Возможно, помимо OpenGL::OpenGL потребуются и другие модули ([OpenGL::GLX, OpenGL::GLU](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenGL.html), например). Вся прелесть таких [импортируемых модулей](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets), что не требуется заботится об `target_include_directories` - все ссылки на либы и пути до хедеров уже добавлены. Теперь можно сменить не только ОС, но и компилятор :). Правда сторонние либы придётся собрать под правильный компилятор.