# Ошибка линковки библотеки (связка C++, boost, python)

Tags: c++, python, boost, cmake, undefined-reference

Собственно следовал [по пути автора](https://habr.com/post/168083/) с целью получить библиотеку с расчетной частью на С++ и всем остальным на Python. Пользуюсь Clion 2018.1.6, MinGW-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0, cкачал CMake  3.13.0-rc1-, Python 3.7 (x86_64) (проверил разрядность, выдало все таки 64), boost 1.68.0 собрал следующим образом:

```
bootstrap
b2 -j12 --stagedir=lib\x64 architecture=x86 address-model=64 --with-python --build-type=complete stage
```

Получил заветные либы, но при сборке мне почему то выдало win-32 (Пересобирал несколько раз из под C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe, и другими опциями). Так и не могу определить под какую разрядность собралось.

Далее начал собирать тестовый проект:
CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(pylibtest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-march=native -O2 -m64 -D_hypot=hypot -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )

message(STATUS "start running cmake...")

set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Boost 1.68.0)# COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR "${Boost_Path}/lib/x64/lib")
    message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()

find_package(PythonInterp 3.7 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.7 REQUIRED)
if(PYTHONLIBS_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES = ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}")
    message(STATUS "PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
endif()

add_library(pylibtest SHARED library.cpp library.h)

if(Boost_FOUND AND PYTHONLIBS_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(pylibtest SYSTEM PRIVATE  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(pylibtest ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

library.cpp

```
#include "library.h"
#include <iostream>

void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}

#include "library.h"
#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("hello", hello);
}
```

Собственно в ответ на Build получаю:

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build "C:\ESI Cloud\Prog\Test\pylibtest\cmake-build-debug" --target pylibtest -- -j 6
Scanning dependencies of target pylibtest
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pylibtest.dir/library.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libpylibtest.dll
CMakeFiles\pylibtest.dir/objects.a(library.cpp.obj):C:/PROGRA~1/boost/BOOST_~1/boost/python/make_function.hpp:38: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python7objects15function_objectERKNS1_11py_functionE'
CMakeFiles\pylibtest.dir/objects.a(library.cpp.obj):C:/PROGRA~1/boost/BOOST_~1/boost/python/def.hpp:91: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python6detail17scope_setattr_docEPKcRKNS0_3api6objectES3_'
CMakeFiles\pylibtest.dir/objects.a(library.cpp.obj): In function `PyInit_hello_ext':
C:/ESI Cloud/Prog/Test/pylibtest/library.cpp:13: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleER11PyModuleDefPFvvE'
CMakeFiles\pylibtest.dir/objects.a(library.cpp.obj):C:/PROGRA~1/boost/BOOST_~1/boost/python/type_id.hpp:160: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python6detail12gcc_demangleEPKc'
CMakeFiles\pylibtest.dir/objects.a(library.cpp.obj): In function `boost::python::converter::expected_pytype_for_arg<void>::get_pytype()':
C:/PROGRA~1/boost/BOOST_~1/boost/python/converter/pytype_function.hpp:67: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python9converter8registry5queryENS0_9type_infoE'
C:/PROGRA~1/boost/BOOST_~1/boost/python/converter/pytype_function.hpp:70: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK5boost6python9converter12registration25expected_from_python_typeEv'
CMakeFiles\pylibtest.dir/objects.a(library.cpp.obj): In function `boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<boost::python::detail::caller<void (*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector1<void> > >::~caller_py_function_impl()':
C:/PROGRA~1/boost/BOOST_~1/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:30: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_baseD2Ev'
CMakeFiles\pylibtest.dir/objects.a(library.cpp.obj):C:/PROGRA~1/boost/BOOST_~1/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:30: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_baseD2Ev'
CMakeFiles\pylibtest.dir/objects.a(library.cpp.obj):library.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFvvENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IvEEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFvvENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IvEEEEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base::max_arity() const'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\pylibtest.dir\build.make:87: libpylibtest.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:72: CMakeFiles/pylibtest.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:84: CMakeFiles/pylibtest.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: pylibtest] Error 2
```

Перелопатил реально много материала решая предыдущие ошибки с `hypot` и т.д., нашел разве что похожие вопросы без ответа на англоязчном стаке и багрепорты в boost и CMake. Уважаемое сообщество, если у вас есть какие-либо идеи по решению этой проблемы, пожалуйста поделись - я, к сожалению, свои уже исчерпал =(

---

**UPD_1**
Действительно, оно того стоило - `find_package(Boost 1.68.0 REQUIRED python)` и `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)` дали понимание того что ищется, а именно:

```
Searching for PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_python-mgw81-mt-1_68;libboost_python-mgw81-mt;libboost_python-mt-1_68;libboost_python-mt;libboost_python
```

Из чего стало ясно что, сборка либ предыдущим способом сформировала либы для msvc. Стал пересобирать boost следующим образом:

```
bootstrap.bat gcc
b2 toolset=gcc --build-type=complete address-model=64 --with-python stage -j12
```

Архитектура теперь определяется нормально (x64), однако проблемой стало то, что boost не собирается, информируя меня о куче ошибкок, как то:

```
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\debug\threading-multi\wrapper.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\debug\threading-multi\exec.o
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/math.h:36,
                 from C:\Program Files\Python37\Include/pyport.h:191,
                 from C:\Program Files\Python37\Include/Python.h:53,
                 from ./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:151,
                 from ./boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13,
                 from ./boost/python/ssize_t.hpp:9,
                 from ./boost/python/object.hpp:8,
                 from ./boost/python/exec.hpp:8,
                 from libs\python\src\exec.cpp:6:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/cmath:1121:11: error: '::hypot' has not been declared
   using ::hypot;
           ^~~~~
In file included from ./boost/python/detail/is_xxx.hpp:8,
                 from ./boost/python/detail/is_auto_ptr.hpp:9,
                 from ./boost/python/detail/copy_ctor_mutates_rhs.hpp:8,
                 from ./boost/python/detail/value_arg.hpp:7,
                 from ./boost/python/object/forward.hpp:10,
                 from ./boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:16,
                 from ./boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
                 from ./boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
                 from ./boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from ./boost/python/object_core.hpp:14,
                 from ./boost/python/object.hpp:9,
                 from ./boost/python/exec.hpp:8,
                 from libs\python\src\exec.cpp:6:
./boost/python/detail/is_auto_ptr.hpp:17:40: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 BOOST_PYTHON_IS_XXX_DEF(auto_ptr, std::auto_ptr, 1)
                                        ^~~~~~~~
./boost/detail/is_xxx.hpp:20:4: note: in definition of macro 'BOOST_DETAIL_IS_XXX_DEF'
    qualified_name< BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS_Z(1, nargs, T) >        \
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./boost/python/detail/is_auto_ptr.hpp:17:1: note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_PYTHON_IS_XXX_DEF'
 BOOST_PYTHON_IS_XXX_DEF(auto_ptr, std::auto_ptr, 1)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/memory:80,
                 from ./boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp:21,
                 from ./boost/get_pointer.hpp:14,
                 from ./boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:11,
                 from ./boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
                 from ./boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
                 from ./boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from ./boost/python/object_core.hpp:14,
                 from ./boost/python/object.hpp:9,
                 from ./boost/python/exec.hpp:8,
                 from libs\python\src\exec.cpp:6:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:53:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
```

Пересобрал раз 5 с разными опциями (bjam, b2, install и без него) в надежде что само пройдет, но неумолимо получаю:

```
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\threading-multi>libboost_python37-mgw81-mt-x64-1_68.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\threading-multi>list.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\threading-multi>libboost_python37-mgw81-mt-x64-1_68.a for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\threading-multi>list.o...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_python37-mgw81-mt-x64-1_68.a for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\threading-multi>libboost_python37-mgw81-mt-x64-1_68.a...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\threading-multi>libboost_python37-mgw81-mt-s-x64-1_68.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\threading-multi>list.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\threading-multi>libboost_python37-mgw81-mt-s-x64-1_68.a for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\threading-multi>list.o...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_python37-mgw81-mt-s-x64-1_68.a for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\link-static\threading-multi>libboost_python37-mgw81-mt-s-x64-1_68.a...
...failed updating 108 targets...
...skipped 20 targets...
```

Есть ли у кого примеры, как все же правильно собирать boost под mingw-w64, возможно кто-нибудь уже сталкивался с подобными ошибками?

---

**UPD_2**

Собрал boost вот с такими ключами, вроде бы без ошибок, файлы либ появились:

```
bootstrap gcc 
b2 -j12 toolset=gcc runtime-link=shared architecture=x86 address-model=64 --with-python cxxflags="-D__int64=\"long long int\" -DBOOST_REGEX_MATCH_EXTRA -D__NO_INLINE__ -D_hypot=hypot"  --build-type=complete --layout=tagged stage
```

в CMakeList.txt внёс изменения:

```
set(Boost_DEBUG                 ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS       ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED     ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    ON)

find_package(Boost 1.68.0 COMPONENTS python37 REQUIRED)
```

Ошибка с `undefined reference to` никуда не исчезла =(

---

**UPD_Last**

Всем спасибо, библиотека собирается и корректно работает без опций `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS       ON)` и `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    ON)`, почему так происходит - неизвестно на англоязычном стаке есть вопрос на эту тему, но он остался без ответа. Возможно требуется пересобрать boost с параметрами link=static и тогда эти флаги заработают, может и нет. Пока что обошелся тем, что собранные либы из stage/lib скопировал к генерируемой либе.pyd

Comment: Если уж вы используете Boost.Python, то не надо ли делать `find_package(Boost 1.68.0)# COMPONENTS system filesystem python REQUIRED)`?

Comment: @arrowd, большое спасибо за наводку, обнаружил что собирал либы под msvc, теперь не могу разгрести завал ошибок собирая с тулсетом gcc.

Comment: [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536547/176217) читали?