# Ошибка компиляции STM32+System Workbench+C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, stm32

Пытаюсь собрать проект для STM32 в System Workbench. Если собрать проект на чистом С (все файлы имеют расширение .c), то все работает без проблем. Есть необходимость использовать С++. Ответы в сети и на разных формах говорят, что нужно просто переименовать файл main.c в main.cpp и конвертировать сам в проект C++. Я проделал это, но при компиляции возникает ошибка:

Building target: 1.elf
Invoking: MCU G++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs -T"../STM32F103C8Tx_FLASH.ld" -Wl,-Map=output.map -Wl,--gc-sections -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -o "1.elf" @"objects.list"   -lm
Src/main.o:(.data+0x10): undefined reference to `__gcov_merge_add'
Src/main.o: In function`_GLOBAL__sub_I_00100_0_main':
main.cpp:(.text._GLOBAL__sub_I_00100_0_main+0x4): undefined reference to `__gcov_init'
Src/main.o: In function`_GLOBAL__sub_D_00100_1_main':
main.cpp:(.text._GLOBAL__sub_D_00100_1_main+0x2): undefined reference to `__gcov_exit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [1.elf] Error 1
makefile:50: recipe for target '1.elf' failed

Подскажите куда смотреть, чтобы решить данную проблему?

Comment: У вас видимо идет сборка с генерацией покрытия (gcov), соответственно отключите ее.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Убрать в настройках проекта соотв. галочку.

Comment: Почитайте ещё [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217) про "undefined reference".