# Ошибка LNK2019 в работающей библиотеке

Tags: c++, http, rest

Решил попробовать подключить эту библиотеку:

https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp

Подключал так:

Project -> properties -> VC++ Directories -> include Directories. Выбрал там путь к папке, а именно

> C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\REST_LIB\include

И при таком коде:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "restclient-cpp/restclient.h"


int main()
{
    RestClient::Response r = RestClient::get("http://google.com");
    return 0;
}
```

Выбивает эту ошибку (P.S Кромешный ужас, сам боюсь):

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "struct RestClient::Response
>   __cdecl RestClient::get(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)"
>   (?get@RestClient@@YA?AUResponse@1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
>   referenced in function _main  ConsoleApplication1 D:\C++
>   Projects\pomogite\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj 1

Окей, если бы именно эта библиотека не подключалась - я бы просто забил. Но так делают почти все библиотеки в моих VS 2015 и 2017.

Что я делаю не так в этой жизни?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b) Вы сделали только первый шаг в подключении библиотеки - указали путь к папке, где препроцессор будет искать заголовочные файлы.

Comment: Вы так и не подключили библиотеку. Вы включили в свою программу *заголовочный файл* библиотеки. Но заголовочный файл к библиотеке имеет примерно то же отношение, как меню ресторана к самому ресторану.

Comment: @AnT, вот попробовал подключить и src и include, все, что только можно. Такая же ошибка..