# Ошибка при попытке скомпилировать что-то с boost::stacktrace

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, c++17, boost-stacktrace

Решил попробовать boost::stacktrace и воспроизвёл простейший [пример](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html) из документации boost. Использую qt-creator 4.8, Cmake 3.10, GCC 7.3, boost 1.69.0.

Код:

```
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void Foo() {
    std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace() << std::flush << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Cmake скрипт:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(fast_test_3)
add_definitions(-DBUILD_TYPE_="${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
add_definitions(-DPROJECT_NAME_="${PROJECT_NAME}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS                 "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread ") #
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG           "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -g -DDREAL_DEBUG -DDREAL_TRACE -fno-inline")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL      "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -Os -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE         "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -O3 -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -O2 -g")

set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)      
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)    
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system) 
include_directories (SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}) 
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES}) 

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Во время компиляции компилятор выдаёт четыре ошибки:

- /.../main.cpp.o:-1: In function `boost::stacktrace::detail::to_string[abi:cxx11](boost::stacktrace::frame const*, unsigned long)':
- /.../main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dladdr'
- /.../main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dladdr'
- :-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

На сколько я знаю boost::stacktrace это хэдеронли библиотека и я не могу понять в чём вообще заключается проблема?

#### UPD:

Вовремя дискусии возник вопрос, действительно ли эта библиотека хэдеронли? Предоставляю [ссылку](http://boostorg.github.io/stacktrace/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html) на место в документации где оговаривается этот момент.

Comment: Пока не смог найти ответ, но по поводу:   << std::flush << std::endl;  хотел отметить, что  std::endl  заодно очищает поток, так что  std::flush  совершенно лишняя писанина.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/317064

Comment: @ARHovsepyan у меня при удалённой отладке на arm машинах иногда не срабатывал вывод без std::flush, даже если там был endl. С тех пор появилась такая привычка, когда я пишу под Linux. Возможно, я что-то тогда неправильно делал. В любом случае спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Видимо вам надо прилинковать `-ldl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убив кучу времени, я решил эту проблему. В общем как оказалось для сборки чего-то с boost::stacktrace на GNU требуется библиотека DL (спасибо @VTT за подсказку). Но что бы CMake всё нормально собрал необходимо добавить в target_link_libraries переменную ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} (при этом наличие или отсутствие флага компиляции -ldl не на что не влияет, не знаю почему). Конечный скрипт выглядит так:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(fast_test_3)
add_definitions(-DBUILD_TYPE_="${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
add_definitions(-DPROJECT_NAME_="${PROJECT_NAME}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS                 "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread ") #
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG           "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -g -DDREAL_DEBUG -DDREAL_TRACE -fno-inline")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL      "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -Os -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE         "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -O3 -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -O2 -g")

set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system)
include_directories (SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```