# Проблема с установкой gotk3

Tags: c, golang, gtk+, gtk3, golang-faq

Не могу установить/переустановить [GTK для Go](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3) windows 7 x64. 
Дело в том, что товарищ не смог справиться с выше-поставленной задачей, и я решил помочь (у меня-же работает). 
Настройка вроде-бы до ужаса примитивна:

- На систему с установленным golang устанавливаем msys2 (64 bit) c MinGW-w64
- В консольке MinGW-w64 с помощью pacman скачиваем всё что нужно
- прописываем в path путь к x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin

В общем всё по инструкции, https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/wiki/Installing-on-Windows с одним отличием mysys - последний.

Обычно этого хватало и go get github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk работал нормально и тянул необходимый пакет, а так-же простой examle.go из примеров работал.

Но не в этот раз.

```
go get github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk
# github.com/gotk3/gotk3/pango
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build074518798\b034\_x002.o: In 
function `_cgo_d7fe93989068_Cfunc_g_value_get_enum':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:56: undefined reference to `g_value_get_enum'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build074518798\b034\_x004.o: In 
function `_cgo_d7fe93989068_Cfunc_g_value_get_boxed':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:62: undefined reference to 
`g_value_get_boxed'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Почему-то GO не видит функцию Си используемую в "pango" С.get_value_get_enum. 
Я решил повторить установку у себя - переименовал папку msys64 -> msys64_ и переустановил его заново - работает.
После чего я переименовал Go -> Go_ и переустановил GO, и только тогда получил ту-же ошибку что и у товарища. Переименовал Go_ обратно в Go опять всё работает, посмотрел версии у старая go1.11.2 вновь установленная go.1.11.4. У товарища замена моей папочкой с go1.11.2 проблему не решило. 
Встал вопрос, чего всё-же ему не хватает, просторы интернета по вышеописанным проблемам молчат.
За ранее признателен за помощь.

Comment: Попробуйте поставить go через pacman внутри msys.

Comment: Спасибо за направление, к сожалению не помогло. Удалил папку c:\Go, установил Go через msys (#pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-go), поправил пути к новому GOROOT, перезагрузился. Но при go get github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk добавилась ещё одна ошибка 
    go build github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gdk: invalid flag in pkg-config --libs: -Wl,-luuid , поправил её с помощью #bash -c "sed -i -e 's/-Wl,-luuid/-luuid/g' C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/gdk-3.0.pc", а в остальном всё то-же самое.

Comment: Про "undefined reference to" вам [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217).

Comment: Спасибо, это Я читал.Но, например [pango-layout.go](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/blob/master/pango/pango-layout.go) импортирует си как-то вот так import "C", а потом, например в строке 194   C.g_value_get_enum((*C.GValue)(unsafe.Pointer(p))) и на выходе мы почучаем ошибку. Хотя другие обращения "C.Xххх" проходят без проблем. Вот тут возникает вопрос почему именно эта одна функция не отрабатывается?

Answer (score 1):

Решено!
Помогло - замена `#cgo pkg-config: pango` на  `#cgo pkg-config: pango gobject-2.0` в файлах `pango-layout.go` и `pango-attributes.go`

Comment: Как давний разработчик, пользующий `gtk`, очень рекомендую вам использовать что-то другое. С `gtk` происходит нечто неприятное: постоянная и умышленная поломка `API` и `ABI`. Разработчики `gtk` называют это интенсивным развитием. Оно вызывает очень серьезные проблемы, особенно в долгосрочной перспективе. Особенно при использовании привязок к другим языкам. Мы долгое время пытались угнаться за вечно ломающимся тулкитом. Но это невозможно. Мне кажется, что все это агрессивное развитие является следствием того, что и сами и разработчики уже не понимают, что со всем этим делать.