# Ошибки при компиляции программы на C++ с использованием libpq для работы с PostgreSQL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, postgresql, libpq

При работе с библиотекой libpq в С++ (библиотека для взаимодействия с сервером PostgreSQL) Visual Studio выдает примерно такие ошибки:

testlibpq.o: In function `main':
testlibpq.o(.text+0x60): undefined reference to`PQsetdbLogin'
testlibpq.o(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `PQstatus'
testlibpq.o(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to`PQerrorMessage'

В официальном мануале сказано, что они могут возникать из-за того, что я забыл добавить параметр -lpq. Но вот куда именно я должен его добавить я так и не понял. Пробовал прописывать его в свойствах проекта C/C++ -> Командная строка и в Компоновщик -> Командная строка в дополнительные параметры, но это не помогает. У меня ещё мало опыта использования Visual Studio и очевидно я просто чего-то не понимаю. Может кто-нибудь хотя бы примерно сказать куда этот параметр прописывать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/317064

Comment: Никуда. Это параметр для компоновщика gcc / clang. Для VC++ вам следует раздобыть библиотеку импорта (.lib), добавить ее в Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies и добавить путь к папке, где лежит библиотека в Linker -> General -> Additional library directories

Comment: @VTT В принципе я так и сделал. Но ошибки почему-то все равно появляются раз за разом.