# Ошибка линковки в Qt5 {Пустой проект}

Tags: c++, qt5, компоновщик, qwidget

При попытке запустить вот такой код :

Source.cpp :

```
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
int main()
{
   QWidget w;
  w.resize(200,200);
   w.show();
 return 0;
}
```

Выводятся такие ошибки:

```
debug\untitled1.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QWidget::resize(int,int)" (__imp_?resize@QWidget@@QEAAXHH@Z) referenced in function main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QWidget::show(void)" (__imp_?show@QWidget@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QWidget::QWidget(class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (__imp_??0QWidget@@QEAA@PEAV0@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z) referenced in function main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl QWidget::~QWidget(void)" (__imp_??1QWidget@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
```

Untitled.pro :

```
QT += widgets
CONFIG += c++11
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
QML_IMPORT_PATH =
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

С Qt никогда раньше не имел дело,возможно,надо какую-то dll подключить?

Так как я понял там Name-Mangling да?

Comment: запустить - в смысле выполнить `untitled.exe` ? А вы это вручную из консоли делаете или из QtCreator ? В Path не хватает библиотек qt-шных

Comment: из Qt я запускаю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/317064