# Создание экземпляра класса в конструкторе другого класса из другого проекта

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, проект

Немножко начал вливаться в C++, но многого пока не знаю. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

В Visual Studio 2017 я создал два пустых проекта: ProjectA и ProjectB. Проекты находятся в одном решении.

В ProjectA есть класс ClassA, разбитый на .h и .cpp.

```
// ClassA header
#pragma once

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA();
    ~ClassA();
};


// ClassA source
#include "ClassA.h"

ClassA::ClassA()
{
}


ClassA::~ClassA()
{
}
```

В проекте ProjectB я создал класс ClassB со следующим содержимым.

```
// ClassB header
#pragma once
#include "ClassA.h"

class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassB();
    ~ClassB();

    ClassA *ca;
};


// ClassB source
#include "ClassB.h"

ClassB::ClassB()
{
    ca = new ClassA();
}

ClassB::~ClassB()
{
}
```

Далее в проекте ProjectB я создал файл main.cpp и создал экземпляр ClassB:

```
#include "ClassB.h"

int main() {

    ClassB *cb = new ClassB();

    return 0;
}
```

При запуске выдало ошибку, в которой никак не могу разобраться.

`Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall 
 ClassA::ClassA(void)" (??0ClassA@@QAE@XZ) в функции "public: __thiscall 
 ClassB::ClassB(void)" (??0ClassB@@QAE@XZ)`

Что это и как это исправить?

Я не нашел ответа на вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B): все функции вроде бы имеют определение, нет виртуальных методов или статических переменных.

Comment: Я не нашел ответа на мой вопрос по предложенной ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш проект B должен использовать код класса A из другого проекта.

Если этот другой проект А - это DLL, то надо брать функции из нее, указав в проекте B линковать библиотеку из проекта А.

Если это просто библиотека lib - тоже надо указать, что надо ее линковать.

Если нет, и это обычный экзешник - то тогда таки добавляйте исходник в оба проекта.

Откуда комипилятору знать, что вы хотите слинковать что-то из одного проекта в другой?

Answer (score 0):

- Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду под "два проекта". В такой конфигурации ProjectA должен быть *библиотекой*, а ProjectB - собственно приложением. У вас ваши проекты сконфигурированы именно так?

  (Если ProjectA будет *динамической* библиотекой DLL, придется предпринять еще некоторые дополнительные шаги.)
- Если да, то в панели проектов Visual Studio есть ветка "References". Вам нужно добавить библиотеку ProjectA в список "References" для приложения ProjectB. В VS2017 это приведет к тому, что библиотека ProjectA будет линковаться к приложению ProjectB.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]