# c++ namespace модуль

Tags: c++, ооп

посмотрел исходники iostream и там вот такая конструкция

```
namespace std {
     extern istream cin;  
     extern ostream cout;     
     extern ostream cerr;     
     extern ostream clog;
}
```

Я попытался сделать тоже самое:

```
class AA {
    public :
        ...
};

class BB {
    public :
        ...
};


namespace OO
{
    extern AA test1;
    extern BB test2;
}
```

но каждый раз при компиляции выкидывает подобное - undefined reference to `OO::test1'
Если делать без extern будет выбивать -  multiple definition. Подскажите, как решить эту проблему? спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b) Вообще так делать не следует - лучше реализовать полноценный синглетон.

Comment: У меня просто такая задача:  объеденить несколько классов в один "модуль", реализация iostream мне показалась вполне приемлемой.

Comment: Приведенный код не производит объединение нескольких классов в один "модуль", он просто объявляет несколько глобальных переменных, которые должны быть определены в какой-то единице трансляции.

Comment: А в чем тогда проблема? не могу понять почему компилятор ругается

Comment: *"которые должны быть определены в какой-то единице трансляции"* у вас они не определены. А если написать без extern - то они будут определены боле одного раза - в каждой единице трансляции, в которую включается этот заголовочный файл.

Comment: Вам нужно в каком-то .cpp файле написать `namespace OO {AA test1; BB test2;}`, не забыв заинклудить хедер с определениями классов. Либо другой вариант: Заменить `extern` на `inline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `<iostream>` вы видите только *объявления* глобальных объектов. А где-то в недрах стандартной библиотеки сидят еще их *определения*.

В вашем коде вы воспроизвели только объявления, а определений не предоставили вообще. Вот и получается ошибка линкера: не найденные определения.

Вам следует выбрать какую-то одну единицу трансляции вашего проекта и там дополнительно предоставить еще и *определения* для этих объектов

```
OO::AA test1;
OO::BB test2;
```

Если вам все равно, где именно будут определены эти объекты, то в современном С++ прямо в заголовочном файле вы можете просто написать

```
namespace OO
{
  inline AA test1;
  inline BB test2;
}
```

Это будет одновременно и объявлением и определением и, благодаря `inline`, не вызовет ошибок множественнного определения.