# Специализация шаблонов и общий код

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

При специализации шаблона под конкретный тип, общий класс используется на ура, а специализация, использующая то же определение метода, что и общий, при использовании этого метода выдаёт ошибку unresolved external symbol.
Т.е. есть класс

```
template <typename CMD>
class Version
{
public:
    Version(ByteVector &byteVector) : byteVector(byteVector) {};

    Object<DATA<CMD>>   cls_DATA();
    Object<USR<CMD>>    cls_USR();
    Object<AUTH<CMD>>   cls_AUTH();
    Object<CONN<CMD>>   cls_CONN();
private:
    ByteVector &byteVector;
};
```

И реализация метода cls_AUTH() в том же .h-файле

```
template<typename CMD>
inline Object<AUTH<CMD>> Version<CMD>::cls_AUTH()
{
    return Object<AUTH<CMD>>(byteVector);
}
```

В том же файле есть специализация с отличием в том, что в этой версии доступен только один метод

```
template <>
class Version<AOPEN>
{
public:
    Version(ByteVector &byteVector) : byteVector(byteVector) {};

    Object<AUTH<AOPEN>> cls_AUTH();
private:
    ByteVector &byteVector;
};
```

Так вот при использовании этого метода в специализации выходит unresolved external symbol. А при попытке определить метод второй раз, для специализации первая ошибка остаётся, и появляется вторая - not an entity that can be explicitly specialized в специализированном определении этого метода.

Comment: Гадание ошибки в коде по пересказу. Покажите код.

Comment: Интересно, к доктору вы тоже когда ходите, говорите просто "доктор, мне нехорошо", а на вопрос о симптомах - "не твое дело! лечи!"? Ищите свою причину [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B)

Comment: Если вы пишете специализацию, то должны определять до конца. Линкерн ищет определение функций этого специализированного класса. так как он  не определяется по шаблону

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно переопределить метод, но не так:

```
template<>
inline Object<AUTH<AOPEN>> Version<AOPEN>::cls_AUTH()
{
    return Object<AUTH<AOPEN>>(byteVector);
}
```

а без `template<>` в начале. Т. е. чтобы было просто:

```
inline Object<AUTH<AOPEN>> Version<AOPEN>::cls_AUTH()
{
    return Object<AUTH<AOPEN>>(byteVector);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Два класса — два определения. Нельзя определить функцию только для одного класса и использовать это определение для объявлений в разных классах. Поэтому, чтобы использовать одну реализацию в разных классах нужно либо использовать наследование, либо свободные функции, либо композицию. При наследовании, думаю, что всё и так понятно. Решение со свободной функцией будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
template<typename CMD>
Object<AUTH<CMD>> cls_AUTH(ByteVector& byteVector)
{
    return Object<AUTH<CMD>>(byteVector);
}

template <typename CMD>
class Version
{
    //..
    Object<DATA<CMD>> cls_AUTH()
    {
        return cls_AUTH<CMD>(byteVector);
    }
    //..
private:
    ByteVector &byteVector;
};

template <>
class Version<AOPEN>
{
    //..
    Object<AUTH<AOPEN>> cls_AUTH()
    {
        return cls_AUTH<AOPEN>(byteVector);
    }
private:
    ByteVector &byteVector;
};
```

С композицией будет то же самое, просто функции будут принадлежать какому-то классу, а в Ваших классах будет объект этого класса, но суть от этого не меняется.

P.S. наследование будет проще всего, т.к. будет гораздо меньше писанины.

Comment: нет двух классов, есть шаблон класса и есть один класс

Comment: @ARHovsepyan специализация это всегда отдельный класс. Так что да, есть как минимум 2 класса, если мы принимаем, что общая версия присутствует не просто для красоты.