# Как использовать классы из одного проекта в другом в Visual studio с++ 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

пытаюсь использовать в своем с++ проекте код из другого проекта. На ресурсах говорят, что достаточно добавить ссылку на другой проект, но это не помогает, #include все равно высвечивается красным. Может я что-то неправильно делаю? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а где код?
я вам порекомендую просто скачать библиотеки и бросить в папку c кодом ( расширение: .h )

Comment: кода как такового нету, я просто пытаюсь связать два проекта так чтобы можно было использовать код одного проекта из другого. О каких библиотеках речь идет  не совсем понимаю, тут не используются библиотеки. Возможно вы имели ввиду сделать либу из проекта а потом кинуть эту либу в другой проект, но меня не устраивает такой подход если честно.

Comment: Может вы язык с С# перепутали?

Comment: как я мог перепутать язык с С#?

Comment: неужели никто не знает как это сделать?

Comment: Ну это в c# можно делать ссылки на другие проекты чтобы их подключить. А в с++ процедура будет ничем ни отличающейся от подключения любого другого стороннего кода - делаете либу, указываете в настройках своего проекта соответствующие параметры для препроцессора, компилятора и линкера и вперед. при этом кидать что-то в свой проект не следует.

Comment: так я вроде разобрался,  сделал либу из первого проекта, во втором проекте указал путь к папке с этой либой, добавил путь к заголовкам в параметре Additional Include Directories во втором проекте, но теперь у меня другая проблема, когда я добавляю #inlude с заголовком из первого проекта  в код второго проекта вместо нормальной компиляции сыпятся ошибки. При этом никаких компиляционных ошибок нету когда я не добавляю заголовок в код, все хорошо компилится. Я хз из-за чего это, я может я чего-то не понимаю так как я ничего не понимаю в c++ и visual studio.

Comment: Поглядите еще [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/Ссылка-на-неразрешенный-внешний-символ-возможные-причины). *"я ничего не понимаю в c++"* - ну так с этого надо было начинать... C++ - это язык с высоким порогом входа, с наскока на нем вряд ли получится сделать что-то вменяемое.

Comment: VTT, я пытаюсь подключить либу "libcds", при этом в самом описании этой либы написано что ее можно как проект открывать в visual studio, я открыл ее в VS и сначала попытался использовать ее как проект, но не получилось, тогда я скомпилировал ее как .lib файл, добавил заголовки и этот .lib файл в другой проект. Но он все равно ругается, когда я его как стороннюю библиотеку подключаю к другому проекту. Я не знаю почему, он же скомпилировался нормально как там вообще могут быть ошибки?

Comment: Причем он походу ругается на иерархию файлов, мол не видит другие файлы в либе, выскакивает ошибка "cannot open source file", но  пути к заголовкам вроде правильно указаны. Я вижу вы получше меня знаете visual studio 2017, не поможете? Если он конечно у вас на данный момент установлен на компе. Я понимаю что возможно я просто туплю,  что там все очень просто и я как полный нуб не поставил нужную галочку в окне настроек VS.Ну мало ли

Answer (score 0):

Заходите в свойства проекта (правой кнопкой на проекте в Solution Explorer - там Properties). В появившемся окне Configuration выбираете All configuration (чтобы не делать одно и то же для Debug, Release и т.п.), в дереве слева выбираете VC Directories. Теперь справа в Include Directories добавляйте папку с вашими файлами, которые Вы хотите добавлять в #include. Только добавляйте, а не стирайте все, что там есть. =)