# Заголовочные файлы на СИ

Tags: c

Выводит ошибку - undefined reference to `add'. Файл add.c виден

main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "add.h"

int main()
{
    int sum;
    sum=add(3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

add.c

```c
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

add.h

```c
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

int add(int x, int y); 

#endif
```

Comment: Значит, не виден. Откуда такая уверенность, что виден?

Comment: Что значит "виден"? "Виден" или "не виден" значения не имеет. Значение имеет компилируете ли вы его и линкуете ли в программу.

Comment: Покажите команды сборки и в `add.c` делаете `#include"add.h"` ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 2):

> undefined reference to `add'

Это сообщение линкера. Значит - в вашем каталоге проекта либо нет файла *add.o*, либо вы не говорите линкеру о том, что его надо включить в модуль. Попробуйте такую команду сборки модуля:

```
gcc main.c add.c -o test
```