# Какой компилятор или среду использовать для работы с книгой Чарльза Петцольда "Программирование для Windows 95"

Tags: c, windows, компилятор

На данный момент я читаю книгу Чарльза Петцольда "Программирование для Windows 95". При компиляции кодов из книги, компилятор выдает множество ошибок, иногда мне удается все же исправить ошибки и программа работает. Возможно ли компилировать код из книги не исправляя ошибок? Я хочу чтобы весь код из книги полностью работал на windows 10. Я использую mingw версии 6.3.0. Я не силен в том, как работает компилятор и зависит ли компиляция на разных версиях операционной системы. Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужен специальный компилятор и определенная версия компилятора?

Это пример кода из книги

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR bzCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static char szAppName[] = "HelloWin";
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wndclass;

    wndclass.cbSize     = sizeof(wndclass);
    wndclass.style  = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc= WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance  = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon      = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor    = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName= NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName= szAppName;
    wndclass.hIconSm    = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    RegisterClassEx(&wndclass);

    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        szAppName,
        "The Hello Program",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC         hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT        rect;

    switch(iMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            PlaySound("hellowin.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
            return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            DrawText(hdc, "Hello, Windows 95!", -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

и ошибки которые выдает компилятор

```
D:\Projects\C++\Kernigan\4 functions and structures>gcc hellowin.c -o a
C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8J0wBY.o:hellowin.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8J0wBY.o:hellowin.c:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to `PlaySoundA@12'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: А почему вы не хотите взять более современные книги Петцольда? Дело в том, что полученные вами навыки по программированию для Win95 будут абсолютно бесполезны.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, у Петцольда нет современных книг по cи или c++. Я хочу иметь дело именно с этими языками программирования. Если я ошибаюсь, будьте добры скинуть ссылку на более современные книги, заранее благодарен. Очень много людей в интернете советуют именно книгу "программирование для Windows95" от Петцольда и я не знаю с чем это связано, скорее всего с тем, что эта книга преподносит информацию доступно и качественно, но я могу и ошибаться, ибо толком книги на эту тематику не читал.

Comment: Давайте разделим "изучение языка С\С++" и "написание прикладных программ для конкретной ОС". По языку С++ можно рекомендовать Александреску, например. Новые издания Петцольда приведены в Википедии https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4,_%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7

Comment: Я оговорился, я имел ввиду, что хотел бы писать прикладные программы на WinAPI. И как я уже говорил, у Петцольда вроде как нет обновленной книги по изучении winAPI.

Comment: Согласен с остальными. Книга, если я правильно понял, написана в 1996 (!) году, а С++ с тех пор сильно изменился. Чтобы потом не переучиваться, советую найти книгу не старее 2011 года (которая рассказывала бы про С++11 или новее).

Comment: Тогда вам правильно советуют с ответом. Петцольд ясно пишет список требований во введении и указывает компилятор.

Comment: Этот исходник можно собрать и с mingw, просто нужно подключить соответсвующие библиотеки. `gcc hellowin.c -lwinmm -lgdi32 -o a`. С другими может повести меньше

Comment: Кстати, если продолжите пользоваться mingw, обновиться не помешает. Последняя версия - 9.2.

Comment: Можно и посвежее взять. "Системное программирование в среде Windows" (Д. Харт), Совершенно не факт, что то, что работало в win95 будет работать в win10.

Comment: В приведенном коде, на первый взгляд, нет ничего заточенного под старые версии компилятора. Разве что используется ANSI строки, а в новых версиях по умолчанию стоит Юникод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> D:\Projects\C++\Kernigan\4 functions and structures>gcc hellowin.c -o a
> C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8J0wBY.o:hellowin.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
> C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8J0wBY.o:hellowin.c:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to `PlaySoundA@12'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Просто необходимо указать библиотеки, функции из которых используешь:

```
gcc hellowin.c -lgdi32 -lwinmm
```

Какие библиотеки необходимы для конкретных функция можно посмотреть, например, в документации: [GetStockObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getstockobject), [PlaySoundA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v%3Dvs.85)) (указана в поле `Library` таблицы внизу страницы).

---

Подробности, что такое `undefined reference` смотри в основном ответе: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b/536547#536547)

Answer (score 2):

Проще взять что-то из семейства майкрософтовских компиляторов (лучше, конечно, VisualC 6.0) - когда писалась книга, все с ними проверялось.