# Не могу подключить билиотеки!

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Подключаю в проект библиотеки

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "winldap.h"
#include "winber.h"
#include "rpc.h"
#include "rpcdce.h"
#include "stdio.h"
```

выдает ошибки будто библиотеки и не подключились

```
D:\cpp_project\newDesktop\LDPA_Query.cpp:39: ошибка: undefined reference to `__imp_ldap_initW'
D:\cpp_project\newDesktop\LDPA_Query.cpp:42: ошибка: undefined reference to `__imp_ldap_set_optionW'
D:\cpp_project\newDesktop\LDPA_Query.cpp:43: ошибка: undefined reference to `__imp_ldap_connect'
D:\cpp_project\newDesktop\LDPA_Query.cpp:44: ошибка: undefined reference to `__imp_ldap_bind_sW'
D:\cpp_project\newDesktop\LDPA_Query.cpp:72: ошибка: undefined reference to `__imp_ldap_search_sW'
D:\cpp_project\newDesktop\LDPA_Query.cpp:84: ошибка: undefined reference to `__imp_ldap_unbind_s'
D:\cpp_project\newDesktop\LDPA_Query.cpp:86: ошибка: undefined reference to `__imp_ldap_msgfree'
D:\cpp_project\newDesktop\LDPA_Query.cpp:95: ошибка: undefined reference to `__imp_ldap_unbind'
```

При сборке qmake выдает следующее

```
:-1: предупреждение: Failure to find: windows.h
:-1: предупреждение: Failure to find: winldap.h
:-1: предупреждение: Failure to find: winber.h
:-1: предупреждение: Failure to find: rpc.h
:-1: предупреждение: Failure to find: rpcdce.h
:-1: предупреждение: Failure to find: stdio.h
```

Использую компилятор MinGW 7.3.0 64-bit for C++

Вопрос, где мне найти эти библиотеки что бы их добавить в проект?

Файл .pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    LDPA_Query.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h \
    windows.h \
    winldap.h \
    winber.h \
    rpc.h \
    rpcdce.h \
    stdio.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    res.qrc
```

Файл .cpp (не мой, позаимствовал для теста)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QString>
#include "windows.h"
#include "winldap.h"
#include "winber.h"
#include "rpc.h"
#include "rpcdce.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void MainWindow::LDAP_query()
{

//Name contains the username

PWCHAR hostName = NULL;
//PWCHAR Domain = NULL;
PWCHAR pMyDN = NULL;
//PWCHAR pUserName;
//PWCHAR pPassword;
LDAP* pLdapConnection = NULL;
ULONG version = LDAP_VERSION3;
//ULONG getOptSuccess = 0;
//ULONG connectSuccess = 0;
INT returnCode = 0;

//  Convert String hostname to a wchar_t*
char const *hostName_2 = "host";
QString Test = QString::fromAscii(hostName_2);
hostName = (WCHAR*)(Test.utf16());

//Connverting Char to WCHAR to connect to Directory
char const *pMyDN_2 = "Ou=directory,Dc=Name,DC=office";
QString test2 = QString::fromAscii(pMyDN_2);
pMyDN = (WCHAR*)(test2.utf16());

//Open Connection
pLdapConnection = ldap_init(hostName, LDAP_PORT);
//Setting Connection Parm's

  ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, (void*)&version);
ldap_connect(pLdapConnection, NULL);
returnCode = ldap_bind_s(pLdapConnection, pMyDN, NULL, LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE);

if(returnCode == LDAP_SUCCESS)
{
    ui->statusbar->showMessage("Connection sucessfull");
}
else
{
    ui->statusbar->showMessage("Connection unsucessfull");
}

//Variables for Search Results
LDAPMessage* pSearchResult;
PWCHAR pMyFilter = NULL;
char const *pMyFilter_2 = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";
QString Test7 = QString::fromAscii(pMyFilter_2);
pMyFilter = (WCHAR*)(Test7.utf16());

PWCHAR pMyAttributes[6];
ULONG errorCode = LDAP_SUCCESS;

pMyAttributes[0] = (WCHAR*)QString("cn").utf16();
pMyAttributes[1] = (WCHAR*)QString("company").utf16();
pMyAttributes[2] = (WCHAR*)QString("department").utf16();
pMyAttributes[3] = (WCHAR*)QString("telephoneNumber").utf16();
pMyAttributes[4] = (WCHAR*)QString("memberOf").utf16();
pMyAttributes[5] = NULL;

errorCode = ldap_search_s(
                    pLdapConnection,    // Session handle
                    pMyDN,              // DN to start search
                    LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, // Scope
                    pMyFilter,          // Filter
                    pMyAttributes,      // Retrieve list of attributes
                    0,                  // Get both attributes and values
                    &pSearchResult);    // [out] Search results

if (errorCode != LDAP_SUCCESS)
   {
       ui->statusbar->showMessage("ldap_search_s failed with");
       ldap_unbind_s(pLdapConnection);
       if(pSearchResult != NULL)
           ldap_msgfree(pSearchResult);
     }
   else
        ui->statusbar->showMessage("ldap_search succeeded \n");


//here i like to receive the user's full name

//Closing Connection
ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);

//ui->Test_Ausgabe -> setText(name);
}
```

Comment: Директивы вида `#include "windows.h"` не подключают в проект библиотеки. Вам стоит ознакомится с порядком сборки в С/С++, прежде всего с препроцессором и линкером.

Comment: Вы не подключаете библиотеки. Только заголовочные файлы, да и тех судя по всему нет.

Comment: чтобы помочь, приведите минимально воспроизводимый .cpp а также файл проекта .pro

Comment: Добавил в вопрос файлы

Comment: Будто? Да у вас указанно что референта нет. Это уже наяву!

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю, меня волнует другое, что еще нужно сделать что бы заработало? Что я еще не добавил в проект? Куда смотреть?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536547/3380