# Ошибка "Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _main в функции ..."

Tags: c++

коллеги. Возникает дурная ошибка в коде. Гуглил, но решения не нашёл. Решил обратиться к Вам. Возникает ошибка "ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _main в функции "int_cdel invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)".

Исходный код:

```
struct spisok
{
    char* fio;
    int klass;
    int school;
};


void vvod(spisok* s)
{


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка ничуть не дурная.

Выполнение программы начинается с функции `main()`. Видимо, вы пытались не просто скомпилировать этот код в объектный, но и собрать в выполнимый файл.

Компоновщик сообщил, что не видит, что же именно запускать...

Comment: Если ответ устроил - принимайте (птичка слева от ответа).