# Error LNK2019: Ошибка на неразрешённый внешний символ в freeglut

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Код:

```
void display(){


}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);//начальная инициализация окна
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);//установка режима отображения
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);//размер окна
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);//начальная позиция на экране
    //вы заметили что вначале идут функции с приставкой glutInit...?, так вот они должны быть первыми, а потом уже все остальные ф-ии.
    glutCreateWindow("Window");//заголовок окна
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);//цвет фона

    // настройка проекции, с этими двумя ф-ми познакомимся поближе чуть позже.
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);//режим матрицы
    glLoadIdentity();//отчищает матрицу

    glOrtho(-100, 100, -100, 100, -100, 100);//cоздаем пространство нашей сцены, в данном случае 3D пространство с высотой, шириной и глубиной в 200 едениц.
    glutDisplayFunc(display);//функция которой мы передаем имя функции для отрисовки окна. 
    glutMainLoop();//запускаем всё проинициализированное
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__exit в функции _glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK@4
1>MSVCRTD.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __CrtDbgReport в функции __CRT_RTC_INIT
1>MSVCRTD.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __CrtDbgReportW в функции __CRT_RTC_INITW
1>MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _strcpy_s в функции "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (?_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPAXPBD@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _strcat_s в функции "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (?_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPAXPBD@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ ___stdio_common_vsprintf_s в функции __vsprintf_s_l
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __wmakepath_s в функции "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __wsplitpath_s в функции "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _wcscpy_s в функции "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ ___vcrt_GetModuleFileNameW в функции "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ ___vcrt_GetModuleHandleW в функции "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ ___vcrt_LoadLibraryExW в функции "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _terminate в функции __except_handler4_noexcept
1>MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4gs.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __except_handler4_common в функции __except_handler4
1>F:\repos\Simulator\Debug\Simulator.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 14
```

Настройки проэкта:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>16.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{462D242F-8D2A-421E-8F03-2D50D7F1CE85}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>Simulator</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>C:\Others\MSVC\freeglut\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Others\MSVC\freeglut\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>opengl32.lib;freeglut.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <EntryPointSymbol>main</EntryPointSymbol>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>C:\Others\MSVC\freeglut\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Others\MSVC\freeglut\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>opengl32.lib;freeglut.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <EntryPointSymbol>main</EntryPointSymbol>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="main.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

В компоновщике путь до библиотек и зависимости указал, в разделе C/C++ путь до каталогов указал.
freeglut взял отсюда - https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/ для MSVC DLL закинул в system32 и SysWOW64. 
Решения нигде так и не нашёл.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: Mikhalio в том вопросе нет решения проблемы.

Comment: Непонятно, откуда у вас MSVCRTD.lib вылезает. Приводите [mcve] обязательно с настройками проекта, используемом компиляторе и glut.

Comment: Использую Visual Studio 2019

Comment: видимо проблема из-за того, что переопределена точка входа (entry point)

Comment: полный бардак, в компоновщике указана subsystem console, а для компилятора нет дефайнов ни _WINDOWS, ни _CONSOLE. Если вам нужен консольный проект, сделайте его из шаблона и модифицуруйте

Comment: @PavelGridin Создал по шаблону с тем же кодом и библиотекой, компилируется нормально но после запуска открывается консоль а не созданное окно, также  при закрытии консоли или завершении программы студия намертво виснет

Comment: разбирайтесь с OpenGL, графическое окно должно быть одновременно с консолью, но студия не должна виснуть