# CMake заголовочные файлы и файлы реализации в разных папках

Tags: c++, cmake

Имеется проект с подобной структурой:

```
include
  | foo
      | first_foo.h
      | second_foo.h
  | bar
      | first_bar.h
      | second_bar.h
src
  | foo
      | first_foo.cpp
      | second_foo.cpp
  | bar
      | first_bar.cpp
      | second_bar.cpp
      | main.cpp
СMakeList.txt
```

Сам **CMakeList.txt** выглядит следующим образом:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(FooBar VERSION 0.1.0)

include_directories("./include")
include_directories("./include/foo")
include_directories("./include/bar")

aux_source_directory("./src/foo" FOO)
aux_source_directory("./src/bar" BAR)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${FOO} ${BAR})
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "first_foo.h"
#include "second_foo.h"
#include "first_bar.h"
#include "second_bar.h"
using namespace tests;

int main()
{
    from_first_foo();
    from_second_foo();
    from_first_bar();
    from_second_bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что при таких параметрах компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

```
undefined reference to 'tests::from_first_foo()'
undefined reference to 'tests::from_second_foo()'
undefined reference to 'tests::from_first_bar()'
undefined reference to 'tests::from_second_bar()'
```

То есть, я так понимаю, что он не может найти файлы реализации. Как сделать так, чтобы он их увидел? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: использование cmake версии 3.0.0 обязательное условие?

Comment: лучше не использовать функции вроде `aux_source_directory` или `file glob` - это будет приводит к проблемам, например в случае переключения между ветками с разным содержимым и т.п. Лучше вручную прописывать source файлы - это самый надежный способ

Comment: Версия CMake не принципиальна. Вручную же прописывать каждый файл, как мне кажется, уж слишком неэффективно по времени. Да, понятное дело, если проект маленький. А если он содержит в себе, например, 100 классов, где каждый реализован в отдельном файле (возьмем, что каждый класс в проекте достаточно объемный и раскидывание каждого в отдельный файл - вполне оправданная затея)?

Comment: даже в этом случае это оправданная затея. Во-первых вы запишите их всего один раз. Во-вторых, как ни парадоксально, чем больше проект, тем больше вы будете испытывать проблем с glob объявлениями. Это связано с тем, что чем больше проект, тем чаще вам нужно переключаться между ветками, над проектом и людей работает больше. Из-за этого и проблем будет возникать больше

Comment: если версия не принципиальна, то порекомендую использовать 3.5 и выше и вручную прописать сырцы - если это не поможет, то проблема может быть только в коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У проблемы одна из двух причин:

- либо `tests::from_first_foo()` и т.д. действительно ни где не реализованы. О причинах и о том как устранить см. основной ответ: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b/536547#536547).
- либо виной всему [`aux_source_directory()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/aux_source_directory.html). Его не рекомендуется использовать для поиска исходников как раз потому, что ни система сборки ни `cmake` не будут видеть вновь добавленные файлы в указанные каталоги, пока cmake'у явно не будет дана команда сгенерировать систему сборки заново.