# Разделил программу на несколько файлов. При компиляции получается вот это. Как исправить?

Tags: c++

Код ошибки

```
   In function `AquariumArray::AquariumArray(unsigned int)': AquariumArray.cpp:(.text+0x55):   undefined reference to `Aquarium::Aquarium()'
```

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "AquariumArray.h"

#define COUNT 2

int main()
{
     AquariumArray aq[COUNT];
     return 0;
}
```

Aquarium.h

```
 #pragma once
 #include <stdio.h>
 class Aquarium
 {
  private:
      float height;
      float length;
      float width;
      float heightLiquid;
  public:
      Aquarium();
  };
```

Aquarium.cpp

```
  #include "Aquarium.h"

  Aquarium :: Aquarium()
  {
       this->height = 0;
       this->length = 0;
       this->width = 0;
       this->heightLiquid = 0;
  }
```

AquariumArray.cpp

```
   #include "AquariumArray.h"

   AquariumArray :: AquariumArray(unsigned length)
   {
       this->array = new Aquarium[length];
   }
```

AquariumArray.h

```
  #pragma once
  #include "Aquarium.h"

  class AquariumArray
  {
   private:
       Aquarium* array;
       unsigned length;
   public:
       AquariumArray(unsigned length=0);        

  };
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: Ощущение, что не все *.cpp в проект включены...