# Линковщик ругается на вынесенные в cpp-шник конструктор и деструктор

Tags: c++

*Да, я видел данный вопрос: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/Ссылка-на-неразрешенный-внешний-символ-возможные-причины](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B), не помогло / не понял / не разобрался / много вариантов, видел множество других вопросов, у меня ошибки всего две, скорее всего однотипные, пж, можно немного конкретики? Ну тупой я для того, чтобы самому понять, какая из 10 разных проблем у меня*

---

**Так компилируется:**

```
template <typename Ts>
class table
{
public:
    std::vector <Ts> data;
    std::string filename;
    table(std::string fn)
    {
        filename = fn;
    }
    ~table()
    {
        data.clear();
    }
};
```

**Так не компилируется:**

```
template <typename Ts>
class table
{
public:
    std::vector <Ts> data;
    std::string filename;
    table(std::string fn);
    ~table();
};
```

+

```
#include "Table.h"

template <typename Ts>
table<Ts>::table(std::string fn)
{
    filename = fn;
}

template <typename Ts>
table<Ts>::~table()
{
    data.clear();
}
```

Никого не подчёркивает, но выдаёт такие вещи:

- error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall table::table(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator >)" (??0?$table@Uemployee@@@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) в функции _main.
- error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall table::~table(void)" (??1?$table@Uemployee@@@@QAE@XZ) в функции _main.

(на другие методы не ругается)
Какая-то тёмная магия, помогите в ней разобраться :\

Comment: Не выносите реализацию шаблонов в .cpp-файл!! Там по ссылке об этом ясно сказано: "Неправильная реализация шаблонного кода.

Например, реализация шаблонного кода помещена в *.cpp файл, хотя она должна находиться полностью в подключаемом *.h файле."

Comment: об этом можете читать: https://overcoder.net/q/1528/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, кхм. Ссылка на клон ENSO? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Не выносите реализацию шаблонов в .cpp-файл!! Там по ссылке об этом ясно сказано: "Неправильная реализация шаблонного кода. Например, реализация шаблонного кода помещена в *.cpp файл, хотя она должна находиться полностью в подключаемом *.h файле."

Да, как оказалось, реализацию шаблонов просто незя выносить из исходника, спасибо

Comment: Читайте здесь: https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1798717.html#post9488987