# sqlapi++ неопределенная ссылка

Tags: c++, ubuntu, postgresql, g++, libpq

Код:

```
#include <SQLAPI.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SAConnection con;

    try
    {
       con.Connect("localhost@db_for_cpp", "lofectr", "<password>", SA_PostgreSQL_Client);
       SACommand cmd(&con, "select * from data");
       cmd.Execute();
       while( cmd.FetchNext() )
            cout<<"name: "<<cmd[2].asString().GetMultiByteChars()<<"\tdata: "<<cmd[1].asString().GetMultiByteChars()<<endl;

    }
    catch(SAException& x)
    {
     printf("ERROR %d: %s\n",
            x.ErrNativeCode(), x.ErrText().GetMultiByteChars());

    }                        

    return 0;
}
```

Команда компиляции:

```
g++ main.cpp -o program -L/home/lofectr/Документы/libs/SQLAPI/lib -I/home/lofectr/Документы/libs/SQLAPI/include/
```

Система: `Linux Ubuntu x64`

Вывод:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пути до библиотеки указанны верно.

В чем проблема?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Comment: 1) ну вот неужели скрин сделать проще, чем скопировать текст из терминала? 2) у вас как минимум в путях кирилица - может проблема и не из-за этого, но это может привести к другим проблемам. 3) `libs/SQLAPI/lib` - а где библиотека?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch 2 - это не проблема, проверил. 3 - всмысле где? По этому пути ._.

Comment: @Данил хотите сказать, что ваша библиотека называется просто `lib` и даже без суффикса?

Comment: @Данил если до сих пор не поняли: да, вы указали папку с библиотекой - а сама библиотека то где? Откуда компилятору знать что вы хотите слинковать?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а как это указать?)

Comment: @Данил да просто пропишите название библиотеки, а не путь к ней

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch на сколько я знаю -L это путь к папке?

Comment: @Данил да, это путь к папке, только, почему-то, вы не знаете что компилятору нужно сказать имя библиотеки. Укажите имя библиотеки с помощью `-l`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch можете скинуть команду? Я всё пробовал уже. Ничего не получается.

Comment: @Данил нет не могу - потому что банально не знаю какую библиотеку вы хотите слинковать

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch SQLAPI++