# Unit Tests для проекта из одного класса

Tags: c++, qt, юнит-тесты, qtcreator

У меня есть проект Qt widgets и я хочу создать тесты для нескольких функций (MainWindow::RPN). Как это сделать через Qt Creator? Ну или как перенести проект на vs и сделать там?
Я перепробовал все что смог нагуглить (и оф документацию, и с хабара).

```
#.pro
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui
RC_FILE = CalculatorIco.rc


CONFIG(testcase) {

    QT += testlib

    HEADERS += \
        testtest.h

    SOURCES += \
        test_main.cpp\
        testtest.cpp

}
else {

    SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
}

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

testtests.cpp

```
//testtests.cpp
#include "testtest.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtTest>

TestTests::TestTests(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void TestTests::first_test()
{
    MainWindow w;
    QString tempString = "2 + 2.2";
    QVERIFY(w.RPN(tempString) == 4.2);
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    double RPN(QString inString);
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
/*...*/
double RPN(QString inQString) {
/*...*/
}
```

Тестовые файлы почти полностью копируют пример выше.

Comment: [Qt Test](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-tutorial.html) Для тестов вам потребуется отдельный проект(если используется `qmake`) либо отдельная цель сборки(при использовании `cmake`)

Comment: Я пробовал и так, но встает проблема доступа к файлам основного проекта, даже на полностью указанный адрес выдает ошибку "No such file or directory". А так же moc file not found

Comment: Какую систему сборки вы используете? `qmake`, `cmake` или что то другое?

Comment: Я использую qmake.

Comment: Добавил в pro тестового проекта подключения из pro основного и удалил moc файл. Скомпилировалось, но теперь ругается на 
test_1::test_1()
{
    MainWindow a;
    int b = a.func(2);
    QVERIFY(b == 4);
}
возможно как-то по другому надо проверять? Я нашёл только такой пример. Ошибки: undefined reference to `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)', и на остальные функции основного проекта.

Comment: @Sen11111 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/398802

Comment: @Sen11111, если тестируемые функции не зависят от UI, то лучше вынести их в отдельный файл. Это позволит протестировать их независимо от класса окна.

Comment: Если я правильно понял нужно исправить в mainwindow.cpp `double RPN(QString inQString)` на  `double MainWindow::RPN(QString inQString)`, это тоже не помогло, ошибка undefined reference to `RPN(QString)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Qt Test` можно использовать и в одиночном проекте, но для этого нужно настроить дополнительные конфигурации сборки.

В файле проекта настраиваем, что собирать и запускать(приложение или тесты) и какие исходники при этом используются.

У меня получился следующий файл проекта:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

#
# Main Sources
#

SOURCES += \
    mainwindow.cxx

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.hxx

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui


#
# Выбор исходников и параметров для сборки
#

CONFIG(testcase) {

#
# для сборки тестов
#

    QT += testlib

    HEADERS += \
        testtests.hxx

    SOURCES += \
        test_main.cxx\
        testtests.cxx

} else {

#
# для сборки приложения
#

    SOURCES += \
        main.cxx
}

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

То есть я создал отдельный `main` и добавил класс для тестов

Содержимое файлов:

```cpp
//test_main.cxx
#include "testtests.hxx"

#include <QtTest>

QTEST_MAIN(TestTests)
```

```cpp
//testtests.hxx
#ifndef TESTTESTS_HXX
#define TESTTESTS_HXX

#include <QObject>

class TestTests : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TestTests(QObject *parent = nullptr);

private slots:
    void first_test();
};

#endif // TESTTESTS_HXX
```

```cpp
//testtests.cxx
#include "testtests.hxx"

#include "mainwindow.hxx"

#include <QtTest>

TestTests::TestTests(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void TestTests::first_test()
{
    MainWindow w;
    QVERIFY(true);
}
```

Тесты собираются при условии, что переменная `CONFIG` содержит `testcase`, иначе приложение

Теперь идем в конфигурацию проекта в `Qt Creator` и добавляем параметры сборки:

- Жмем "добавить", выбираем тип и вводим название(можно скопировать и переименовать имеющиеся)
- Правим "Основное - каталог сборки"
- Разворачиваем "Сборка, этапы - qmake"
- в поле "дополнительные параметры" вводим `CONFIG+=testcase`

[image: qmake add unittest]

Можно попробовать собрать и запустить тесты

[image: qmake test success]

Добавим тест для какой либо логики из `MainWindow`

```cpp
void TestTests::second_test()
{
    MainWindow w;

    QString test{QString::fromUtf8("demo")};

    QCOMPARE(w.someMetod(test), test.size());
}
```

[image: second test]

**Дополнение**

> то появляются две ошибки: undefined reference to `MainWindow::RPN(QString)' и error: ld returned 1 exit status.

У вас в заголовочном файле `RPN` объявлена как *метод* класса `MainWindow`

А в файле реализации(`cpp`) как простая *функция*

При вызове в тесте вы используете `RPN` как *метод*. Но тело метода не определено.

Решение:
Так как `RPN` не зависит от приватных полей класса `MainWindow`, то можно сделать ее свободной функцией, что так же облегчит ее тестирование(не нужно создавать объект класса)

Для этого в файле `mainwindow.h` вынесите ее за пределы объявления класса:

```cpp
double RPN(QString inString);

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

//    double RPN(QString inString);
```

В файле теста замените вызовы метода на вызов функции

```cpp
void TestTests::first_test()
{
    // MainWindow w;
    QString tempString = "2 + 2.2";
    QVERIFY(/*  w. */RPN(tempString) == 4.2);
}
```

P.S.: для сравнений двух значений лучше использовать `QCOMPARE`

Comment: В таком виде у меня все работает, да. Но если изменить содержимое first_test() на MainWindow w;
    QString tempString = "2 + 2.2";
    QVERIFY(w.RPN(tempString) == 4.2);
то появляются две ошибки: undefined reference to `MainWindow::RPN(QString)' и
error: ld returned 1 exit status.
В самой IDE файлы mainwindow.h и mainwindow.cpp подключены, на include "mainwindow.h" тоже не ругается, однако все равно не воспринимает ссылку.

Comment: @Sen11111, `undefined reference` означает, что вы что то недоподключили в файле проекта.

Comment: @Sen11111, Обратите внимание, что перед _методом_ класса в файле реализации указывается имя класса.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Последний раз выдавало `undefined reference` в другом методе, в котором при написании мне пришлось оставить `double RPN(QString inString);` дабы оно работало, а после изменения функции на метод, эта строка выдавала ошибку.