# Не удаётся подключить динамическую библиотеку (GCC)

Tags: c, winapi, gcc

Попробую написать минимальный воспроизводимый пример.
Есть загрузчик динамической библиотеки load.c (не могу разобраться, что он делает, но по методичке должен работать):

```
#include "load.h"
#include "funcs.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void LoadRun (const char * const s)
{
    void * lib;
    void (*fun)(void);
    
    lib = LoadLibrary (s);  
    fun = (void (*)(void)) GetProcAddress ((HINSTANCE) lib, "func");
    if (fun == NULL) printf ("Cannot load function.\n");
    else fun();
    FreeLibrary ((HINSTANCE) lib);
}
```

load.h:

```
void LoadRun (const char * const s);
```

Некоторые функции для обработки данных funcs.h:

```
short SomeFunction (...);
```

Главная функция, в которой должна загружаться динамическая библиотека, после чего вызываться функция по обработке данных SomeFunction:

```
#include "load.h"

int main ()
{
    ...
    LoadRun ("SomeLib.dll");
    SomeFunction ();
}
```

При помощи компилятора GCC пытаюсь создать exe-файл программы. Есть готовые файлы SomeLib.dll, Load.dll, объектный файл программы main.o, но при вводе:

```
gcc -o I:\...\main.exe I:\...main.o -L./ -lLoad
```

появляется ошибка:

```
main.o: undefined reference to 'SomeFunction'
```

Если я правильно понимаю, компилятор пытается найти SomeFunction не в динамической библиотеке и на этапе компиляции думает, что функция не была объявлена. Как избежать этой ошибки компиляции?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае главной ошибкой было не разобраться в работе функции LoadRun.
Во-первых, функция SomeFunction вызывалась в главной функции (main), которой ничего не известно об этой функции и её расположении в памяти. Функция LoadRun получает адрес функции, загруженной из динамической библиотеки, помещает его в указатель fun и вызывает эту функцию через указатель. Можно передать указатель на SomeFunction в главную функцию и оттуда вызывать SomeFunction через этот указатель.
Во-вторых, не совпадали типы аргументов fun и вызываемой функции. Указатель fun должен иметь тот же порядок и те же типы аргументов, что и вызываемая функция SomeFunction, чтобы компилятор не ругался на неверное приведение типов при вызове GetProcAddress. Для функции SomeFunction (short * array, short size):

```
void (*fun)(short * array, short size);
...
fun = (void (*)(short int *, short int)) GetProcAddress ((HINSTANCE) lib, "SomeFunction");
```

В-третьих, как видно из примера выше, имя вызываемой функции передаётся в качестве аргумента GetProcAddress, поэтому несовпадение имён может привести к ошибке.