# Как использовать библиотеку MediaInfoLib в C++

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь получить информацию об аудиофайле с помощью MediaInfo.h

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <MediaInfo/MediaInfo.h>
#define MediaInfoNameSpace MediaInfoLib;
#define _itot itoa
#include <string>

using namespace MediaInfoNameSpace;
.
.
.
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_1_clicked()
{
   MediaInfoLib::MediaInfo MI;   
   MI.Open(file_str);   
   auto codec=MI.Get(stream_t::Stream_Audio, 0, "Format");
   std::cout << "Codec :" << codec << std::endl;   
   MI.Close();

}
.
.
.
```

На этот раз при компиляции вылетает ошибка: error: undefined reference to `MediaInfoLib::MediaInfo::MediaInfo()’

Comment: пытаетесь присвоить `size_t` `std::string`.

Comment: Поменял std::string media_info на size_t media_info, теперь уже выходит ошибка:
'''
error: undefined reference to `MediaInfoLib::MediaInfo::MediaInfo()'
'''
--  я еще забыл, я указал после строк #include ...
строку:
using namespace MediaInfoNameSpace;

Comment: @Helg1980 [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/Ссылка-на-неразрешенный-внешний-символ-возможные-причины)

Comment: Приведите [mre] короче

Comment: Сейчас мне сказали, что библиотека MediaInfoLib не прилинкована к собираемому исполняемому файлу. А как ее прилинковать правильно?

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Внимательно прочтите описание методов `Open` и тогда появится ответ:

```
        ...

        /// Open a file and collect information about it (technical information and tags)
        /// @brief Open a file
        /// @param File_Name Full name of file to open
        /// @retval 0 File not opened
        /// @retval 1 File opened
    size_t Open (const String &File_Name);

        /// Open a Buffer (Begin and end of the stream) and collect information about it (technical information and tags)
        /// @brief Open a buffer
        /// @param Begin First bytes of the buffer
        /// @param Begin_Size Size of Begin
        /// @param End Last bytes of the buffer
        /// @param End_Size Size of End
        /// @param File_Size Total size of the file
        /// @retval 0 File not opened
        /// @retval 1 File opened
    size_t Open (const ZenLib::int8u* Begin, size_t Begin_Size, const ZenLib::int8u* End=NULL, size_t End_Size=0, ZenLib::int64u File_Size=0);

        ...
```

**!! Оказывается правильный вопрос - "как собрать и подключить библиотеку `MediaInfoLib`", значит мой ответ не об этом.**

Comment: В проекте, кроме использования заголовка, нужно еще подключать саму библиотеку для линкера. А метод `Open` возвращает целое `size_t`, в описании это указано и "расшифровано".

Comment: В подкаталоге проекта `MediaInfoLib/Project` есть куча файлов под различные системы сборки - читайте, экспериментируйте. Сперва нужно собрать саму либу, потом ее проинсталлить в нужные каталоги. Ну а потом уже ее подключать. "Как подключать" - вопрос неточный. А как вы и чем собираете своей проект? Используете ли какие системы сборки, или вручную вызываете компилятор и линкер? Слишком много неизвестных условий.

Comment: В Qt Creator на Manjaro Linux, компилятор gcc. 
Я сейчас думаю не проще ли подключить библиотеку QMediaMetaData, но еще не знаю как с ней работать. Меня в принципе устроит любой способ.

Comment: В QtCreator'е есть три системы сборки: qmake, cmake, qbs

Comment: Если `Qt`, то явно лучше `QMediaMetaData`, потому "как из коробки". А использовать внешнюю либу - только тогда, когда не хватает чего-то.

Comment: На самом деле эта `MediaInfoLib` достаточно хреново документирована. Поэтому, как я говорил, лучше использовать Qt'шные классы, раз таковые имеются.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html